# The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, odp.net, oracleclient

I'm trying to use the **Oracle ODP.NET 11g (11.1.0.6.20) Instant Client** on my ASP.net project as a **Data Provider** but when I run the aspx page I get a "*The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client*" error message.  Any help would be appreciated.

I've referenced the Data Provider in Visual Studio 2005 and the code behind looks like this:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
..

OracleConnection oOracleConn = new OracleConnection();
oOracleConn.ConnectionString =
    "Data Source=MyOracleServerName;" +
    "Integrated Security=SSPI";
oOracleConn.Open();

//Do Something

oOracleConn.Close();
```

The error for the page looks like this:

```
Exception Details: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

Source Error: 
Line 21: 
Line 22: 
Line 23:             OracleConnection oOracleConn = new OracleConnection();
Line 24:             oOracleConn.ConnectionString =
Line 25:                 "Data Source=MyOracleServerName;" +

[OracleException (0x80004005): The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client]
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize() +494
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..cctor() +483

Stack Trace: 
[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception.]
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..ctor() +0
   Boeing.IVX.Web.RoyTesting.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\CE218C\Desktop\IVX.Net\Web\IVX\RoyTesting.aspx.cs:23
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +15
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +33
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +47
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1436
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I only installed the **Oracle Data Provider for .NET 2.0 (11.1.0.6.20)** and I did not install the **Oracle Instant Client (11.1.0.6.0)**.

I just installed it and the error disappeared!

Comment: Can you simply copy the 4 instant client DLL's into the same folder as your EXE, instead of installing the client? (these files: oci.dll
orannzsbb11.dll
oraocci11.dll
oraociicus11.dll)

Comment: @Chris: Yes, you can.  In my experience, though, you need oci.dll, orannzsbb11.dll, oraociicus11.dll, oraops11w.dll, and oracle.dataaccess.dll

Comment: Other way around for me - I'd installed the client, but not the provider

Answer (score 97):

I've been looking into this problem further, and you simply need to grab all the appropriate DLL's from the same downloaded version of ODP.Net and put them in the same folder as your Exe file, because ODP.Net is fussy about not mixing version numbers.

I've explained how to do this here: http://splinter.com.au/using-the-new-odpnet-to-access-oracle-from-c
Here's the gist of it though:

- Download ODP.Net
- Unzip the file
- Unzip all the JAR's in it
- Grab these dll's that were just unzipped:

  - oci.dll (renamed from 'oci.dll.dbl')
  - Oracle.DataAccess.dll
  - oraociicus11.dll
  - OraOps11w.dll
  - orannzsbb11.dll
  - oraocci11.dll
  - ociw32.dll (renamed from 'ociw32.dll.dbl')
- Put all the DLLs in the same folder as your C# Executable

Comment: Your solution worked for me -- found your blog post before I found this. You are the man. Thanks! :-)
Also, using the latest version of the ODAC, I didn't need to unzip any of the JARs...the .dll files were located in various directories in my oracle home. A simple windows search turned them up very quickly.

Comment: Also, I was using the latest version of ODAC (11.2.0.1.2) on my development machine, and the only files I needed were: oci.dll, Oracle.DataAccess.dll, oraociei11.dll, OraOps11w.dll. As Chris points out, MAKE SURE THEY'RE IN THE SAME FOLDER AS YOUR EXECUTABLE. ;-)

Comment: Sounds like the newer version makes it easier to find the dll's. Great! Now how long till oracle rolls them into one simple dll...

Comment: Chris' strategy and Pandincus' library set worked for me.  I'm calling the oracle client through PowerShell, so I put the library set in the PowerShell executable directory.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with the Oracle.DataAccess.dll for .net framework 4, only for the one for .net framework 2. Does someone found which files are needed for .Net 4 version?

Comment: Excellent; this worked for me too! Note that [the most current download](http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/instantclient/112020/instantclient-basic-nt-11.2.0.2.0.zip) contains the DLLs directly.

Comment: thanks! saved me a lot of time making my app work easily on other computers that didn't have the client installed

Comment: Working even for .NET 4 (using Pandincus comment and ODAC 11.2.0.3.0 XCopy ver).

In case you have error "Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection'." just ensure your app.config (or web.config) has:

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add
        name="Local Oracle Data Provider for .NET"
        invariant="Local.Oracle.DataAccess.Client"
        description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET"
        type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

Comment: @Pandincus: suggest replacing oraociei11.dll (124 MB) with light version oraociicus11.dll (34 MB) also works.

Comment: Download the Xcopy version of ODP.NET to make this process a little more straightforward. It's a few DLLs plus some batch files to copy them, update the GAC and make some registry updates. You can embed it into your own install.

Comment: copied all files from my local oracle client directory into the `bin` directory of my aspx website and make the reference to the copied `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` -> error gone and working :) Thanks for the post!

Comment: If your `ORACLE_HOME` system variable set and TNSNAME is correct it works for me.

Comment: You should probably use the C# managed driver these days if you can :)

Comment: This solution may fail if your customer has a (normal) Oracle Client installation because `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` is installed in [GAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache). In such case `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` is taken from GAC (which has precedence over folder of your .exe) but the other DLL's are taken from folder of your .exe. This can cause the "version is not compatible" error.

Comment: thank you so much finally after 3 hours your solution worked for me

Answer (score 52):

You should "ignore" all the x86/x64 talk here for starters and instead try the ODP.NET Managed Driver (if you are using .Net v4+):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/

[Oracle ODP.net Managed vs Unmanaged Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583289/oracle-odp-net-managed-vs-unmanaged-driver)

Avoid all the "unmanaged" what DLL what architecture issues! :D (about time Oracle).

***The NuGet package (also works for 11g):***

[image]

***The old / manual method:***

For info on how to convert to using the *managed* libraries:

- First, here is a great code comparison of *managed* vs *unmanaged*: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/intro005.htm#ODPNT148
- Ensure you have downloaded the *ODP.NET, Managed Driver Xcopy version only*
- From the downloaded zip file, copy and paste into your project directory:

  - *Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.dll*
  - *Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll*
- Add a reference to *Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll*
- Ensure your exe is released (added to *Application Folder* in VS2010) with both dlls

Comment: Its good news that Oracle finally has a fully managed driver. Lugging around that 100mb dll has been a real burden.

Comment: the managed driver works great for me - I've had no issue since moving over to it / you can set your projects back to AnyCPU etc and it works great :)

Comment: Just so everyone is aware, while the Managed provider is nice, it lacks a lot of features that the full provider allows for. Namely, Oracle's built in encryption.

Comment: Justin is correct, for example you need an extra platform-specific DLL to get some kinds of transactions... Justin, would you be able to elaborate (or provide a link to list) on what is missing from the managed provider, if you have access to that? :)

Comment: Oracle's documentation tends to be "scattered" to say the least. Here's a good link on some [unsupported methods](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/win.121/e17732/intro004.htm). Additionally, the driver itself comes with a `readme` that outlines some limitations.

Comment: Good answer, but does it work for 11g? I can only find the 12c version of ODP.NET Managed Driver.

Comment: @Zenadix off the top of my head I think the driver is only for version 12... But why not try it and see if it will still let you connect to an 11g database server? I have a feeling it might go backwards in that way.

Comment: @TodThomson I've verified that ODAC 12c Release 2 (12.1.0.1.2) Manager Driver is backwards compatible with Oracle 11g Database. Also, note that .NET Framework 4.0 or later is required.

Comment: Usage of managed driver is the final solution! i've a nitghtmare everytime i think all the time spent when i had a type mismatch

Answer (score 33):

This can be caused by running a 64bit .NET runtime against a 32bit Oracle client. This can happen if your server you are running the app on it 64 bit. It will run the .NET app with the 64bit runtime. You can set the CPU flag on your project in VS to run in the 32bit runtime.

Comment: Just ran into this one. Worked in a (32-bit) test app, then fell over in IIS. Rather than require all the assemblies involved to be 32-bit, I changed to a 32-bit AppPool.

Answer (score 30):

Let's make some kind of summary:

Error message **"The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client"** can be caused by several reasons. Meanwhile the error message can have different flavors, e.g. **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."** or **"Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess,' or one of its dependencies"**

- You have no Oracle Client installed. In this case the error message is indeed misleading.

Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET, i.e. file `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`) is not included in Oracle Instant Client, it has to be installed separately (download from [32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html)  or [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)) or you have to select according option in Oracle Universal Installer (OUI).

Note, when installing the Oracle Data Provider >= 12.1, then the provider is not automatically registered into GAC. You have to register it manually if needed, see Oracle Doc [2272241.1](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2272241_1.html).

- The version of ODP.NET does not match installed version of Oracle Client. You have to check even the minor version number! For example, `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` Version **4.112.3.0** is not compatible with Oracle Client **11.2.0.4**. Check versions of ODP.NET and Oracle Client carefully. You can use [sigcheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck) on `oraociei*.dll` and/or `OraOps*w.dll` to get version of Oracle Client.

  Be aware of different numbering scheme. File version **4.112.3.0** means: **.NET Framework Version 4, Oracle Release 11.2.0.3.x**.

  There are ODP.NET version "1.x", "2.x" and "4.x". These numbers are related to Microsoft .NET Framework versions 1.0.3705/1.1.4322, 2.0.50727 and 4.0.30319. Version "1.x" was available until Oracle Client 11.1. Version "4.x" was introduced with Oracle Client 11.2
- The architecture (32bit or 64bit) of ODP.NET does not match your application architecture. A 32bit application works only with 32bit Oracle Client/ODP.NET respectively a 64bit application requires 64bit Oracle Client/ODP.NET. (Unless you use **ODP.NET Managed Driver**)
- The .NET Framework version do not match. For example, if you compile your application with Target .NET Framework 2.0 then you cannot use ODP.NET version 4.x. The .NET Framework target version must be equal or higher than version of ODP.NET.
- The version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` on your development machine (i.e. the version which is loaded while compiling) is higher than the version on the target machine.
- Be aware that `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` might be loaded from [GAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) which by default takes precedence over any locally provided file.
- Newer release of ODP.NET requires higher Microsoft .NET Framework version. For example ODP.NET version 21.4 requires .NET Framework 4.8. Check the System Requirements in the *"Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide"* of your release.

**Solutions**

- Consider to use the ODP.NET Managed Driver, it can be downloaded from Oracle page: [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html).
  There you only have to copy `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` file to your application directory, nothing else is required. It works for both 32bit and 64bit.
- In your `*.csproj`, resp. `*.vbproj` edit your reference to ODP.NET like this:

  ```
   <Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess">
     <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
     <Private>False</Private>
   </Reference>
  ```

Attributes like `Version=...` or `processorArchitecture=...` are not required. <s>Your application will load the correct `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` depending on selected architecture and target .NET framework (provided that it is installed properly)</s>
 -> not 100% verified

- In case you do not know the version of Oracle Client on target machine (e.g. it might be the machine of your customer): Go to the download page mentioned above and download the least **XCopy** version of Oracle Data Access Components. Extract the zip and copy just the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` file to your local machine. In your VS project make a reference to this (most likely outdated) DLL. The version of this DLL is the least version of ODP.NET your application will work with. When you run your application then the Publisher Policy in GAC will redirect to actually installed version.
- I don't think it is a smart approach to take single DLL's and copy them to certain folders. It may work on a "naked" machine but if your target machine has installed any Oracle products there is a high risk for version mismatch. Uninstall any Oracle products from your machine and make a fresh installation. Have a look at [How to uninstall / completely remove Oracle 11g (client)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client) it order to get a really clean machine.
- In case you have to work with 32bit and 64bit applications at the same time, follow this instruction to install both versions on one machine:

Assumptions: Oracle Home is called `OraClient11g_home1`, Client Version is 11gR2.

- Optionally remove any installed Oracle client
- Download and install Oracle x86 Client, for example into `C:\Oracle\11.2\Client_x86`
- Download and install Oracle x64 Client into different folder, for example to `C:\Oracle\11.2\Client_x64`
- Open command line tool, go to folder %WINDIR%\System32, typically `C:\Windows\System32` and create a symbolic link `ora112` to folder `C:\Oracle\11.2\Client_x64` (see below)
- Change to folder %WINDIR%\SysWOW64, typically `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` and create a symbolic link `ora112` to folder `C:\Oracle\11.2\Client_x86`, (see below)
- Modify the `PATH` environment variable, replace all entries like `C:\Oracle\11.2\Client_x86` and `C:\Oracle\11.2\Client_x64` by `C:\Windows\System32\ora112`, respective their `\bin` subfolder. Note: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ora112` must not be in PATH environment.
- If needed set yor `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable to `C:\Windows\System32\ora112`
- Open your Registry Editor. Set Registry value `HKLM\Software\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1\ORACLE_HOME` to `C:\Windows\System32\ora112`
- Set Registry value `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1\ORACLE_HOME` to `C:\Windows\System32\ora112` (not `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ora112`)
- You are done! Now you can use x86 and x64 Oracle client seamless together, i.e. an x86 application will load the x86 libraries, an x64 application loads the x64 libraries without any further modification on your system.

Commands to create symbolic links:

```
cd C:\Windows\System32
mklink /d ora112 C:\Oracle\11.2\Client_x64
cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64
mklink /d ora112 C:\Oracle\11.2\Client_x86
```

Some notes:

- Both symbolic links must have the same name, e.g. `ora112`.
- In case you want to install ODP.NET manually afterwards, take care to select appropriate folders for installation.
- Despite of their names folder `C:\Windows\System32` contains the x64 libraries, whereas `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` contains the x86 (32-bit) libraries. Don't be confused.
- Maybe it is a wise option to set your `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable (resp. `TNS_ADMIN` entries in Registry) to a common location, for example `TNS_ADMIN=C:\Oracle\Common\network`.

Comment: This IMO has more knowledge to take away than the actual answer. So if I have a x86 application for .net 4 and the database version is in 9i, then what client version would a user need to have if they have 32 or 64-bit Windows? Oracle says any client version is compatible with any db version. Is the answer with 32-bit users install the 32-bit version and 64-bit users install 64-bit version and use the ODP.NET Managed Driver to decide which OS it's talking to?

Comment: When you use the ODP.NET Managed Driver then it is not required to install any Oracle client - that's the main advantage of it. It works with both, x86 and x64 applications. Without "ODP.NET Managed Driver" a x86 application requires also an x86 (i.e. 32-bit) Oracle Client, no matter what the database server architecture is.

Comment: I just ran into "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable needs to be installed"--you should add that to your summary.

Comment: I don't think this error is related or caused by Oracle or ODP.NET

Comment: It works for me, I install `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` from nuget package `Oracle.DataAccess.x86`, and its Dll Version is `2.112.1.0`, so I match install Oracle Client with version `Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (x64)` [HERE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.html)  then problem solved!

Comment: but managed data access wont work for OracleBulkCopy for uploading bulk excel

Comment: @BN, yes you are right. However, limitations of ODP.NET managed driver are not the topic here. See also [Differences between the ODP.NET Managed Driver and Unmanaged Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/intro004.htm#ODPNT8146) and [Configuration differences between ODP.NET, Managed Driver and ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/InstallConfig.htm#ODPNT8173)

Comment: i have .net framework 4 and oracle.dataaccess "4.121.2.0" what version oracle client should i use ? i installed ODAC122010Xcopy_x64 and got a version error in visual studio

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya The ODAC includes the client libraries and the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`, thus your question does not make much sense. Did you compile your application as 64-bit? Perhaps you have installed a different version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` which have precedence. Check your GAC (dll and redirection policies) with `gacutil` tool.

Answer (score 8):

After several hours of troubleshooting, I found this issue to be caused by having Oracle.DataAccess.dll (v4.0) in my projects bin directory, but the runtime also loading Oracle.DataAccess.dll (v2.x) from the GAC. Removing and readding the Oracle.DataAccess entry in the project references solved the problem for me.

The other files mentioned here did not appear to be necessary in my situation.

## UPDATE

The root cause of the "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client" error is (generally) that the managed assembly is attempting to load unmanaged libraries which do not match versions. It appears you can force the Oracle driver to use the correct libraries by specifying the library path in the web.config[<sup>1</sup>](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20434_01/doc/win.112/e23174/featConfig.htm#BABCBFDJ)

```xml
<configuration>
  <oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>
      <add name="DllPath" value="C:\oracle\bin"/>
      <!-- ... -->
    </settings>
  </oracle.dataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution give me the idea that work after 2 days (I have Visual Studio 2010 Net 4, Oracle 10g client)...I see GAC and of course I have installed 3 vertions of Oracle.DataAccess.dll, I unistalled all (and delete invalid machine.config keys in "DbProviderFactories"), and re-install only the ODAC1120320 x64. And It works.

Answer (score 6):

install ODP.Net on the target machine and it should solve the issue... copying the dll's does not look a good idea...

Answer (score 6):

For Oracle 11g (11.1.0.7.20) I had to add the following dlls along with my Exe to work.

1. oci.dll
2. OraOps11w.dll
3. oraociicus11.dll (pretty huge close to 30mb)
4. Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Comment: You want to say 130 MB

Answer (score 3):

It would seem to me that though you have ODP with the Oracle Istant Client, the ODP may be trying to use the actual Oracle Client instead.  Do you have a standard Oracle client installed on the machine as well?  I recall Oracle being quite picky about when it came to multiple clients on the same machine.

Answer (score 3):

i have the same problem but in my case i can't just copy the dlls into the bin folder, then i only 'rebind' the assembly version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>    
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89B483F429C47342" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.112.2.0" newVersion="2.112.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did to solve this problem that persisted for 3 long hours:

1. Under Oracle home located at `C:\oracle\product\11.2.0` I had a folder called `client_1` where I had previously installed `ODP.NET` bits for Windows 64 bits.
2. Later while trying to debug my ASP.NET Web API app with Visual Studio 2012, I kept getting this error message: ***The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client***.
3. Searching Google I found that this was happening because I was using `ODP.NET` 64 bits. Then I grabbed `ODP.NET` for Windows 32 bits and installed it but I kept getting the same error message.
4. **SOLUTION:** deleted the folder `client_1` and resinstalled `ODP.NET` 32 bits. Somewhat the installer was mixing bits from the 64 bit version with the 32 bit version. Go figure...
5. Now I'm happy again and I can open a new `OracleConnection`. FINALLY! :)

Answer (score 3):

TLDR Version:

- Use the 12c [100% managed provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583289/oracle-odp-net-managed-vs-unmanaged-driver/17618179#17618179) instead.
- If you must use the old provider, you need to point Oracle.DataAccess.dll to the unmanaged Oracle Client Dlls that are of the correct version.  If you have multiple Oracle Clients installed on your machine that maybe a simple as including the "DllPath" configuration variable (see below) in you app config, but you may also need to install a new oracle client to point to.

Full version:

First, lets make sure we understand the components of the old unmnaged provider (not the new 12c 100% managed provider).  It's made up of two pieces:

1. the managed .net component - Oracle.DataAccess.dll
2. the unmanaged (non-.net) client

Simply speaking, Oracle.DataAccess.dll is nearly just a wrapper, translating .net instructions into ORACLE-NET instructions for the unmanaged client.

That said, when you load Oracle.DataAccess there is a order in which it tries to locate the unmanaged client dlls that it needs.  From the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/win.121/e17732/InstallODP.htm):

> The Oracle.DataAccess.dll searches for dependent unmanaged DLLs (such
>   as Oracle Client) based on the following order:
>
> 1.Directory of the application or executable.
>
> 2.DllPath setting specified by application config or web.config.
>
> 3.DllPath setting specified by machine.config.
>
> 4.DllPath setting specified by the Windows Registry.
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Oracle\ODP.NET\version\DllPath
>
> 5.Directories specified by the Windows PATH environment variable.

So in your case, your app followed this process above and found a path that has unmananged dlls that are too old relative to the Oracle.DataAccess.dll assembly that you are using.

It could just be that the only Oracle Client install on that machine is too old.  But this comes into play if you have more than one client installed on the machine and the unmananaged files were found first in a different but older installation.  If the later, the simple thing to do is use the dllPath configuration variable in your config and point it at the correct Oracle Home Bin folder:

```
<configuration>
  <oracle.dataaccess.client> 
    <add key="DllPath" value="c:\oracle\product\1.1.0-xcopy-dep\BIN"/>
  </oracle.dataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

If you want to install a fresh copy of the client, the [xcopy version](http://www.brothersincode.com/post/Oracle-ODPnet-xcopy-deployment-for-aspnet.aspx) is the smallest and contains the "instant client" and point the DllPath above to this new location.  But any oracle client install will work.

But if you want to avoid all this unmanaged client resolution stuff, see if you can update your app to use the 100% managed provider instead - it truely is just one or two managed assemblies,without any dependency on unmananged files.

Its also possible that you aren't loading the Oracle.DataAccess.dll that you think you are if it is installed in both your bin directory and your GAC, but I think that is the less likely senario.  See the [assembly resolution process](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pranav_rastogi/2010/10/17/asp-net-assembly-loading-from-gac-or-bin/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Does the IIS/IWAM user have permissions on the Oracle directory? Can you connect to this data source using another app, such as Excel or Access?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. I deleted (and forgot that I had deleted) oraociei11.dll after compiling the application. And it was giving this error while trying to execute. So when it cant find the dll that oraociei11.dll, it shows this error. There may be other cases when it gives this error, but this seems to be one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Also look for IIS Application pool Enable 32-bit true or false flag, when you see this message, some oracle forum directed me for this!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still having this problem: based on this article

http://oradim.blogspot.com/2009/09/odpnet-provider-is-not-compatible-with.html

I found out that my server was missing the Microsoft C++ Visual Runtime Library - I had it on my dev machine because of the Visual Studio installed. I downloaded and installed the (currently) most recent version of the library from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523

Ran the setup and the oracle call from C# made it!

Comment: Dude....Oracle....can we have a little discussion? Come over here, in the corner.  Listen man, I spent all day figuring out what the hell "provider not compatible" was supposed to mean, only to find out later that it's because some installation dependency was not met.  Please--no--I *demand* that you make your installer *check* for these dependencies at installation time, and *warn the user* if it is not met.  Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I've had to come back to this stackoverflow question on multiple occasions, and a different answer applies to me every time.  What a waste of time and money this has caused.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't go down the road of getting new DLL's. We had a bunch of existing projects that work perfectly fine and it was only my new project that was giving me headache so I decided to try something else.

My project was using an internally developed Internal.dll that depended on Oracle.DataAccess.dll `v4.112.3.0`. For some reason, when publishing, Visual Studio always uploaded `v4.121.0.0`, even though it wasn't explicitly specified in any of the config files. That's why I was getting an error.

So what I did was:

1. Copied Internal.dll from one of the successfully running projects to my web site's `/bin` (just to be on the safe side).
2. Copied Oracle.DataAccess.dll from one of the successfully running projects to my web site's `/bin`.
3. Add Reference to both of them from my web site.
4. Finally Oracle.DataAccess reference showed up in `myWebSite.csproj`, but it showed the wrong version: `v4.121.0.0` instead of `v4.112.3.0`.
5. I manually changed the reference in `myWebSite.csproj`, so it now read:

   ```
   <Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86">
     <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
     <HintPath>bin\Oracle.DataAccess.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   ```

Comment: It's a *really* bad idea to add a reference to dlls in a bin folder.

Comment: The `bin` and `obj` folders are *output* folders; this is where dlls go when you build your project.   You should be able to delete these folders at any time without creating conflict.  Usually these folders are *ignored* in source control.  The standard practice is to create an `External References` folder where you put your referenced dlls.

Comment: @notfed Seems you're right. Will keep this on my mind.

Comment: As named it is only a **hint** path for the compiler, not a forcing reference. First the GAC is searched for Oracle.DataAccess.dll. It should work even if you delete the `HintPath` entirely.

Answer (score 2):

This issue could by happen while using unmanaged oracle reference if you have more than one oracle client , or sometimes if you reference different version
There is two way to solve it  :

1. First and fast solution is to remove unmanaged reference and use the managed one from NuGet see this before to go with this option [Differences between the ODP.NET Managed Driver and Unmanaged Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/intro004.htm#ODPNT8146)
2. Second solution is to fix project unmanaged target version like the below :

- First Check oracle project reference version (from project references/(dependencies > assemblies ) > Oracle.DataAccess right click > properties):

  [image] 
   
  [image]

Then check oracle GAC version

- got to gac from run (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly"
  [image]
- Check the platform that matches with you project platform  
   
  [image]
- to check you target platform (right click on your project > properties) 
   
  [image]
- From gac folder search to Oracle.DataAccess  
   
  [image]
- Right Click on Oracle.DataAccess > properties > details and check version  
   
   [image]
- if you notice the versions are different this is an the issue and to fix it we need to redirect assembly version (in startup project go to config file and add the below section )

```xml
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="4.121.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

like this
[image]

oldVersion : should be cover your project version
newVersion : GAC version
publicKeyToken : From GAC

 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem, because the Oracle.Data.dll assembly on a network share was updated by our DBA's. Removing the reference from the project, and adding it again solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just two steps to solve this issue.

1. go to advance setting of application pool and set 'Enable 32 bit Application' flag to True.
2. Make sure all Dlls in your Bin is 32 bit version now...

best of luck.

Comment: @mazhar-abbas, Can you pls. point out in which I can I set 'Enable 32 bit Application? Is it in IIS or Project?

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had to work on an older project where the solution and all contained projects were targeted to x32 platform. I kept on trying to copy Oracle.DataAccess.dll and all other suggested Oracle files on all the places, but hit the wall every time. Finally the bulb in the head lit up (after 8 hours :)), and asked to check for the installed ODAC assemblies and their platform. I had all the 64-bit (x64) ODAC clients installed already but not the 32 bit ones (x32). Installed the 32-bit ODAC and the problem disappeared.

*How to check the version of installed ODAC: Look in folder C:\Windows\assembly. The "Processor Architecture" property will inform the platform of installed ODAC.*

Eight hours is a long time for the bulb to light up. No wonder I always have to slog at work :).

Comment: Note, `C:\Windows\assemblies` just shows assemblies up to .NET framework version 2.0. Version 3.x/4.x are not displayed, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213105/oracle-dataaccess-dll-not-shown-in-explorer-although-it-is-installed-in-gac

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem after I installed Oracle Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015, and then fighting with Oracle for a good hour.  I decided to try reinstalling Oracle client again instead of this mess with file copying, config changes, etc., and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue and the root cause was that GAC had 2 oracle.dataaccess versions i.e. v4.0_4.112.2.0 and v4.0_4.112.4.0 . My application was referring to v4.0_4.112.2.0 , so when I removed v4.0_4.112.4.0 from GAC, it worked fine.

GAC path : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess

Before : 
[image]

After :
[image]

To remove a version, one can simply delete the corresponding folder from GAC.

Answer (score 1):

So, for anyone still battling this demon, keep 2 things in mind:

1. What version of **Oracle Database Client** you need.
2. Whether you need the 32bit or 64bit version.
   These 2 depend on your application and Oracle.DataAccess .dll version.

I kept getting this error because I didn't have the correct Oracle Database  Client version installed. I only had the 19c installed when I needed the 11g. You can have multiple versions installed with no problem whatsoever.

After installing the 32bit 11g Oracle Database Client, that finally did the trick for me. You may find older versions of the Oracle Database Client in Oracle's Software Delivery Cloud, just look for them carefully, they're there.

Answer (score 0):

- On a 64-bit machine, copy "msvcr71.dll" from C:\Windows\SysWOW64 to
  the bin directory for your application.
- On a 32-bit machine, copy "msvcr71.dll" from C:\Windows\System32 to
  the bin directory for your application.

http://randomdevtips.blogspot.com/2012/06/provider-is-not-compatible-with-version.html

Answer (score 0):

Chris' solution worked for me as well.  I did however get a follow error message that states:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Apparently, in the foreign language of Oraclish, that means that your program are either targeting all platforms, or 32-bit machines.
Simply change your target platform in Project Properties to 64-bit and hope for the best.

Comment: That's actually .NETish, not Oraclish

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Oracle.DataAccess.dll  v4.121.2.0. with 2- homes installation (32 and 64 bit versions). 32-bit version workerd, 64-bit version didn't.

In my case (after 2 days of trying) I found that the problem was permissions on the 64-bit-home version. **Many Directories** in that version had exclusively overridden permissions where "Authenticated Users" role did not have "Read" access, which is set by default on the parent directory. Those sub-directories included "bin", "network/admin",  "nls", "oracore", "RDBMS" and possibly others. I found them by filtering out "ACCESS DENIED" result in "Process Monitor" (Procmon.exe) utility from sysinternals. Once the permissions were inherited from the parent directory to those child subdirectories everything started to work.

I didn't what to override the permissions on the whole oracle home so I did them one directory at a time, but I guess if you don't worry about security so much you can reset it on the whole corresponding oracle home directory.

Answer (score -3):

Lots of theoretical answers here, but here comes a working example with code that you can copy and paste and test immediately:

1. I installed the Oracle Express database **OracleXE112** which already comes with some preinstalled demo tables.
2. When you start the installer you are asked for a **password**. I entered "xxx" as password. (not used in production)
3. My server runs on the machine **192.168.1.158**
4. On the server you must explicitely allow access for the process TNSLSNR.exe in the Windows **Firewall**. This process listens on port 1521. If you get a timeout error from the below code check your firewall.
5. **OPTION A:** For C# (.NET2 or .NET4) you can download **ODAC11**, from which you have to add Oracle.DataAccess.dll to your project. Additionally this DLL depends on: OraOps11w.dll, oci.dll, oraociei11.dll (130MB!), msvcr80.dll. 
   These DLLs must be in the same directory as the EXE or you must specify the DLL path in: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\ODP.NET\4.112.4.0\DllPath`. On 64 bit machines write additionally to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Oracle\...`
6. **OPTION B:** If you have downloaded **ODAC12** you need Oracle.DataAccess.dll, OraOps12w.dll, oci.dll, oraociei12.dll (160MB!), oraons.dll, msvcr100.dll. The Registry path is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\ODP.NET\4.121.2.0\DllPath`
7. **OPTION C:** If you don't want huge DLL's of more than 100 MB you should download ODP.NET_Managed12.x.x.x.xxxxx.zip in which you find `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` which is only 4 MB and is a pure managed DLL which works in 32 bit and 64 bit processes as well and depends on no other DLL and does not require any registry entries.
8. The following C# code works for me **without any configuration** on the server side (just the default installation):

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
or
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

....

string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
    + "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.158)(PORT=1521)))"
    + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)));"
    + "User Id=SYSTEM;Password=xxx;";

using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb)) 
{
    conn.Open();
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection  = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "select TABLESPACE_NAME from DBA_DATA_FILES";

        using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(dr["TABLESPACE_NAME"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A fairly overkill to install entire Oracle database server when you just need a running client.

Comment: You answer is poor anyway. There is no need to copy any Oracle dll"s to application directory because by default installation you find them through ‰PATH% (unless you modify it by your own)  The Registy hint applies only for.version 4.x and works only for the 32-bit Oracle client. However mismatchrs 32-bit vs. 64-bit is the main topic of this question.

Comment: You comment shows that you did not read my answer. If I want to write an application that communicates with an Oracle server there is no need to install anything from Oracle. I just use the above mentioned DLL and distribte it with my application. So there will be nothing in the PATH variable on the end-user's machine. By the way using the PATH variable (which comes from the old DOS age from 1980) is highly deprecated in modern software. My answer recommends OPTION C which does not need any registry paths and does not depend on 32 or 64 bit. I mentioned OPTIONS A and B only for completeness.

Comment: I think without proper %PATH% setting your Windows will not work at all - even in version 10. I mentioned in my answer that it is not smart to manually copy any Oracle dll's with your application. I don't know the source code of these dll's but there might be more dependencies on your customer side which you don't see, e.g. triggered by language settings, character sets, time zone, etc. When I make a trace with `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` then the program loads in total 35 Oracle DLL's! Better make a normal installation of Oracle Client - unless you use ODP.NET Managed driver, of course.

Comment: You are wrong. I'am not talking about Oracle.DataAccess.dll. Once again as you don't read:  I'am talking about OPTION C. Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll does not have any dependencies as I already wrote above. It works on 32 and 64 bit and does not depend on registry entries. Instead of posting your theories, why don't you simply try it? Create a project that uses this DLL and run it on a virgin Windows installation. It works. I use this since years. My clients have tested it on all Windows versions without ANY problem. As you see your comments and your downvote are completely foolish.

Comment: Your OPTION C is absolutely fine but your OPTION A and B are weak. They may work only under certain conditions. Most likely they work for you but they are not suitable for a generic solution.

Comment: You don't tell me ANything new. Therfore I described the advantage of OPTION C which is obviously the recommended option. But it can only be used in a C# project. For a C++ project OPTION C is not usefull. Finally all this discussion shows only that you did not read thoroughly what I wrote or you did not understand. So why do you downvote my answer which is 100% correct?

Comment: I think I mentioned my concerns: (1) Installing a database is useless, i.e. an overkill. (2) Option A and B work only under certain conditions, for example it does not read any NLS-Settings from Registry (for which you need file `oracle.key`). For compatibility you have to take also minor versions into account. `Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.2.0` does not work with `OraOps11w.dll` version 2.112.4.0 for example.

Comment: I'am wasting my time with you.