# WPF - Binding to Oracle database

Tags: wpf, data-binding, database-connection

In WPF, how is binding to an Oracle database achieved?

#### Existing solutions

1. *Linq* (all 3 required)

   - [Simple Demo of Binding to a Database in WPF using LINQ-SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24192/Simple-Demo-of-Binding-to-a-Database-in-WPF-using)
   - [Using LINQ to SQL with Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276495/using-linq-to-sql-with-oracle)
   - [Building a LINQ Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//ee672195.aspx)
2. *ADO.net*

   - http://erkapeblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/data-binding-and-adonet-in-wpf.html
3. *ODAC*

   - not sure how

It'll also help if you have tried any of the above approaches and have links to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the 2nd solution **(ADO.net)** that I listed in the question and it worked!

#### Steps to follow

1. Install an *Oracle client* (I used Oracle 11g). Apparently, an [instant client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272998/do-i-still-need-to-install-oracle-client-if-using-microsoft-odbc-for-oracle-to-c) can also be used.
2. Follow the steps in this [article](http://erkapeblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/data-binding-and-adonet-in-wpf.html).
3. Small **typo** in the article: The name of the ListBox is incorrectly referred in code as listBox instead of listID.
4. **Connection String** that worked for me ([source](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle#p19)):

> SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;