# Up-To-Date way of deploying app to client machines without Oracle Installed?

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle, deployment

Can anyone provide a more updated way of accomplishing this? I've included all of the steps mentioned here [Deploy a .Net application with Oracle Client 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828626/deploy-a-net-application-with-oracle-client-11?rq=1), but to no avail. When I run the app on the client machine without Oracle installation, I still get the OraOracle provider not registered exception. I have a C# Windows Application and I'm using System.Data.OLEDB as my connection. Please help!

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provider is a bit of a pain to deploy. Something that is not explicit in the link you provide is that you should set the bitness of your project accordingly because the dlls are native code. Don't build for 'Any CPU'.

Oracle is -- finally -- creating a 100% managed provider, which should ease the pain of deployment *a lot*. It's currently in beta 2: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/odpmbeta-1696432.html.

FWIW DevArt also has a 100% managed provider.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So does this support Oledb or do I have to redo my coding to ODP.Net?

Comment: Keep in mind it's beta software. Also there are some advanced features that are missing. But _in theory_ changing the namespace from Oracle.DataAccess to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess is all. A bit more information regarding how to configure your connection strings and such: http://blog.vijay.name/2012/11/oracle-managed-odp-net/

Comment: Unfortunately, the site doesn't load. Currently im using System.Data.OLEDB as my namespace so im hoping this is compatible.

Comment: oups sorry I read to quickly, I thought you were using the Oracle provider. I don't think you can connect to an Oracle database through OLEDB without installing the Oracle thin client first.