# Deploying ASP.NET application which access oracle database?

Tags: asp.net, oracle10g, odac

I have just developed .net application using **visual studio 2008** on **windows 7** which accesses **remote oracle database** **10g** using ODAC `ODTwithODAC1020221.exe` and Oracle **10g express edition** as it automatically installs oracle client. I do not certainly know what else is installed on my development computer but on **I could connect to oracle database succesfully on my development machine via .NET** . Now as application is complete its time to deploy it on server . Server we are using is Windows Server 2003. I installed oracle express edition and ODAC on deployment machine. I created deployment package by right clicking  solution explorer of VS2008 menu and selected option publish and created deployable files on local disk. I copied all these files in virtual directory of IIS of windows server 2003. But when **I could not connect to website from server it gives error as**

> System.TypeInitializationException:
>   The type initializer for
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection'
>   threw an exception. --->
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException
>   The provider is not compatible with
>   the version of Oracle client at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize()
>   at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..cctor()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..ctor(String
>   connectionString) at
>   WebApplication1._Default.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   D:\SunilS\DOTnet\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Default.aspx.cs:line
>   32

Answer (score 0):

although a different oracle version, this [person seemed to have the same exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client) and found a solution