# Unable to load DLL "OraOps10.dll"

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2008, oracle10g

Hi dear all my friends,

I got some oracle problem in my c#.net window based application.I am using oracle 10g express version and vistual studio 2008.
I added Oracle.DataAccess dll to my project and declare the oracle connection and institiate it, that application is working properly in server pc 
but it shows error message in client machine.The error message is 
"Unable to load DLL 'OraOps10.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)".
I got that error at 
"`OracleConnection oraCnn = new OracleConnection();`". 

What is OraOps10.dll and how I solve that problem? Do I need to install some oracle client application in client?
Please give me the right way.

Thanks.

Regards,

Chong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the whole Oracle Client, which includes native libraries, not just Oracle.DataAccess.dll which is a managed .NET wrapper on it. See here for more information: [ODAC 11.2 Release 3 (11.2.0.2.1) with Xcopy Deployment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html)

Comment: i still have the problem after installing the whole oracle client

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya you should ask another question with your (recent) details, things may have changed since

Comment: the first answer in this thread helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client/1258317#comment137671066_1258317