# How to uninstall / completely remove Oracle 11g (client)?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How to uninstall or completely remove Oracle 11g (client)?

Running `deinstall.bat` doesn't work.

**Edit:** Further discussion related to why this question was closed and deleted: [Why was this question related to uninstalling the Oracle Database Client deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190441)

Comment: Covered at Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/256762/how-do-i-completely-remove-oracle-11g

Answer (score 141):

Assuming a Windows installation, do please refer to this:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/ManualOracleUninstall.php

> - Uninstall all Oracle components using the Oracle Universal Installer (OUI).
> - Run regedit.exe and delete the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE key. This contains registry entires for all Oracle products.
> - Delete any references to Oracle services left behind in the following part of the registry:
>     `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Ora*` It should
>     be pretty obvious which ones relate to Oracle.
> - Reboot your machine.
> - Delete the "C:\Oracle" directory, or whatever directory is your ORACLE_BASE.
> - Delete the "C:\Program Files\Oracle" directory.
> - Empty the contents of your "C:\temp" directory.
> - Empty your recycle bin.

Calling additional attention to some great comments that were left here:

- Be careful when following anything listed here (above or below), as doing so may remove or damage any other Oracle-installed products.
- For 64-bit Windows (x64), you need also to delete the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE` key from the registry.
- Clean-up by removing any related shortcuts that were installed to the Start Menu.
- Clean-up environment variables:

  - Consider removing `%ORACLE_HOME%`.
  - Remove any paths no longer needed from `%PATH%`.

This set of instructions happens to match an almost identical process that I had reverse-engineered myself over the years after a few messed-up Oracle installs, and has almost always met the need.

Note that even if the OUI is no longer available or doesn't work, simply following the remaining steps should still be sufficient.

<sub>([Revision #7](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8450982/7) reverted as to not misquote the original source, and to not remove credit to the other comments that contributed to the answer. Further edits are appreciated (and then please remove this comment), if a way can be found to maintain these considerations.)</sub>

Comment: For 64 bit windows, you need also to delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE key

Comment: First, be careful when deleting "C:\Program Files\Oracle", it may contain other products too. Second, you may need to clean your start menu manually ;)

Comment: Don't forget to clean up your path settings and remove the ORACLE_HOME environment variable.

Comment: its mildly annoying that you used / instead of \ :P

Comment: @gbtimmon - I assume you are referring to the registry paths.  I had simply quoted as-was from the original article.  Regardless, they are fixed now.  :-)

Comment: Looks like C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory or C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory is where stuff is.

Comment: Can not find uninstall in Oracle Universal Installer in 11gr2

Answer (score 11):

There are some more actions you should consider:

- Remove Registry Entries for MS Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC)

Note: on the Internet I found this step only at a single (private) page. I don't know if it is required/working or if it breaks anything on your PC.

- Open Regedit
- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSDTC\MTxOCI`
- Add an x before each string for `OracleOciLib`, `OracleSqlLib`, and `OracleXaLib`
- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSDTC\MTxOCI`
- Add an x before each string for `OracleOciLib`, `OracleSqlLib`, and `OracleXaLib`

  Otherwise these files, if they exist, will still be in use next time you reboot, and unable to be deleted.
- Remove environment variable `ORACLE_HOME`, `ORACLE_BASE`, `TNS_ADMIN`, `NLS_LANG` if exist

Check also Oracle doc to find all Oracle related environment variables, however apart from variables listed above they are very rarely used on Windows Client: [Oracle Environment Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/bi.1111/b32121/pbr_rfap001.htm#RSPUB23916)

- Unregister oci.dll

  - Open a command line window (Start Menu -> Run... -> cmd)
  - Enter `regsvr32 /u oci.dll`, resp. `%windir%\SysWOW64\regsvr32 /u oci.dll`
  - In some cases the file `%ORACLE_HOME%\bin\oci.dll` is locked and you cannot delete it. In such case rename the file (e.g. to oci.dll.x) and reboot the PC, afterwards you can delete it.
- Remove Oracle .NET assemblies from Global Assembly Cache (GAC). You do this typically with the [gacutil](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) utility, if available on your system. Would be like this:

  ```
    gacutil /u Policy.10.1.Oracle.DataAccess
    gacutil /u Policy.10.2.Oracle.DataAccess
    gacutil /u Policy.1.102.Oracle.DataAccess
    gacutil /u Policy.1.111.Oracle.DataAccess

    gacutil /u Policy.2.102.Oracle.DataAccess
    gacutil /u Policy.2.111.Oracle.DataAccess
    gacutil /u Policy.2.112.Oracle.DataAccess
    gacutil /u Policy.2.121.Oracle.DataAccess
    gacutil /u Policy.2.122.Oracle.DataAccess

    gacutil /u Policy.4.112.Oracle.DataAccess
    gacutil /u Policy.4.121.Oracle.DataAccess
    gacutil /u Policy.4.122.Oracle.DataAccess

    gacutil /u Oracle.DataAccess
    gacutil /u Oracle.DataAccess.resources

    gacutil /u Policy.4.121.Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
    gacutil /u Policy.4.122.Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
    gacutil /u Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
    gacutil /u Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.resources
    gacutil /u Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC
    gacutil /u Oracle.ManagedDataAccessIOP
    gacutil /u Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework
  ```

  - Entry `System.Data.OracleClient` should not be removed, this one is installed by Microsoft - not an Oracle component!
- Instead of `gacutil /u ...` you can also use `OraProvCfg /action:ungac /providerpath:...` if OraProvCfg is still available on your system. You may find it at `%ORACLE_HOME%\odp.net\managed\x64\OraProvCfg.exe`.
- With a text editor, open XML Config file `%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config` and delete branch `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>`, if existing.
- Do the same with:

  ```
       %SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
       %SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
       %SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config
       %SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config
  ```

  Instead of editing the XML Config file manually you can also run (if OraProvCfg.exe is still available on your system):

  ```
   %ORACLE_HOME%\odp.net\managed\x64\OraProvCfg.exe /action:unconfig /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 
   %ORACLE_HOME%\odp.net\managed\x86\OraProvCfg.exe /action:unconfig /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319
   %ORACLE_HOME%\odp.net\managed\x64\OraProvCfg.exe /action:unconfig /product:odp /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 
   %ORACLE_HOME%\odp.net\managed\x86\OraProvCfg.exe /action:unconfig /product:odp /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319
  ```
- Check following Registry Keys and delete them if existing

  ```
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx\ODP.Net
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\ODP.Net
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework6
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\odp.net.managed
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework6\

    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx\ODP.Net
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\ODP.Net
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework6
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\odp.net.managed
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework6\

    HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver
    HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Unmanaged Driver
    HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\Oracle Provider for OLE DB
  ```
- Delete the Inventory folder, typically `C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory`
- Delete temp folders `%TEMP%\deinstall\`, `%TEMP%\OraInstall\`, `%TEMP%\OraInstall\` and `%TEMP%\oraremservicev2` (e.g `%TEMP%\CVU_11.1.0.2.0_domscheit`) if existing.
- Delete service `OracleRemExecServiceV2` and `Oracle%ORA_HOME_NAME%MTSRecoveryService`

  ```
  sc stop OracleRemExecServiceV2
  sc delete OracleRemExecServiceV2
  rmdir %TEMP%\oraremservicev2 /S /Q

  sc stop Oracle%ORA_HOME_NAME%MTSRecoveryService
  sc delete Oracle%ORA_HOME_NAME%MTSRecoveryService
  ```

Comment: To remove items from the GAC, you might need to use gacutil.exe which comes with visual Studio.  'gacutil /u Oracle.DataAccess' for example.

Comment: If you couldn't find GAC , follow [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mortens/2010/11/09/access-denied-trying-to-uninstall-assemblies-from-gac/)

Comment: Also delete oracle* and policy*Oracle* folders from  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32" and "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64".

Comment: Also delete OraInstall* folders from "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp"

Comment: @Gokul, better write: delete from folder `%TEMP%` which can point to different folder.

Comment: I don't think you should delete anything directly from GAC assembly folders. Use gacutil tool for this.

Answer (score 7):

Do everything suggested by ziesemer.

You may also want to remove from the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\<any Ora* drivers> keys     

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers<any Ora* driver> values
```

So they no longer appear in the "ODBC Drivers that are installed on your system" in ODBC Data Source Administrator

Comment: Don't forget the 32 bit entry on a 64 bit Windows: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\...`

Comment: Be careful with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\Microsoft ODBC for Oracle`. This driver is provided by Microsoft, i.e. part of your Windows installation. When you remove it you will not get it back when you make a new Oracle Client installation.

Answer (score 2):

Do everything suggested by ziesemer.

You may also want to :

- Stop the Oracle-related services (before deleting them from the
  registry).
- In the registry, look not only for entries named "Oracle"
  but also e.g. for "ODP".