# How can I completely uninstall oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How can I uninstall Oracle 11g from my laptop? The uninstall program that comes with the software doesn't completely uninstall all the components. I tried it with Oracle12c and it left a lot of programs. I tried to delete the files manually but some dll files in the BIN directory were are not accessible. I want to do the right thing with 11g. Any suggestions?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you want to uninstall Oracle Database or Oracle Client?

Comment: Both because with the DB administrator tool I could only delete the most recent DB

Comment: This question has a better fit on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ than here (Linux uninstall for database is here, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36648/completely-uninstall-oracle-server-on-linux).  Assuming you are on a windows laptop, the someone already answered that here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client.

Answer (score 4):

There are some problems when I uninstall Oracle 11g (on Window 10) from my installed path "D:\app\" .This is my solution to remove oracle manually:

1. Delete D:\app{user}\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1 
   and all Oracle's files from D:\app\
2. If you can not delete these files, need to change the owner or add permissions

   - Properties>Security> Advanced> Change Owner> Advanced>Find now> Choose Users
   - Sometime you need to add permissions to Users: Properties>Security>Edit> Add Users> Allow ...
3. Delete C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle, C:\Oracle
4. Delete C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Oracle -
   OraDb11g_home1
5. Run regedit.exe>

   - delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Oracle
   - delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ORACLE
6. Delete  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/Ora*
7. Start Run>Computer Management> System Tools>Local Users and Groups> Delete
   all Oracle's users and groups
8. Restart windows.
   Hope helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use the `deinstall` tool as recommended by Oracle.

Then if this fails have a look at this document: [Manually Removing the Remaining Oracle Database Client Components (11.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32007/deinstall.htm#CIHGGGBB), it provides detailed instruction how to remove everthing.

This documentation is for Oracle Client 11.1, however the principle should be the same for 12c. Actually the documentation for 10.2 is even more complete: [Manually Removing the Remaining Oracle Database Client Components (10.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14312/deinstall.htm#CIHGGGBB)

Perhaps some files are locked and you can not delete them by default, for example file `oci.dll`. Solution is to rename the file, e.g. `oci.dll_x` and then reboot your PC. After reboot you can delete the file.

Note, in case you installed 32-bit Oracle the Registry key is `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\...` instead of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\...`

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

Before deinstalling oracle software, make sure you have deleted the oracle databases (and other services) running from the ORACLE_HOME

I have written about the different methods in which you can [remove Oracle software from Linux](https://support.dbagenesis.com/knowledge-base/deinstall-oracle-software/) server:

- Using deinstallation tool with runInstaller
- Using deinstallation tool under ORACLE_HOME
- Manual Oracle uninstall

Comment: Your username matches the author of most of the site's courses. Linking to something you're affiliated with (e.g. a product or website) without disclosing it's yours *in your post* is considered spam on Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).