# How do I deinstall Oracle Instant client?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to remove Oracle 11.2.0.1 Instant Client from a Windows 7 machine.  I ran the OUI to remove it, but a popup displayed telling me to run [oracle_home]/deinstall/deinstall.  Except that there is no deinstall/deinstall in the oracle_home for the Instant Client (there is for other clients).  Apparently Oracle failed to include a deinstall for the Instant Client.

Comment: Ken - OUI is the Oracle Universal Installer.  The Oracle Client cannot be uninstalled using the Windows Control Panel.

Comment: There is no installer either. Just delete the folder you expanded the original distribution zip(s) into?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: [How can I completely uninstall oracle 11g?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727721/how-can-i-completely-uninstall-oracle-11g/28728711#28728711)

Comment: Simply remove the folder. The only problem might be with ODBC drivers. ODBC driver dll has to be explicitlly registered with Windows system, so uninstall might require un-registration or even system reboot.

Answer (score 3):

You can run setup.exe one more time and install Oracle Administration Assistant for Windows in the same ORACLE_HOME directory, use Custom installation type
[image]). 
After install check the folder and you'll see deinstall directory. Run the deinstall.bat as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

The OUI shows a tree structure of the oracle instant client. Check the node of the client , not the root of the tree structure.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my response to this, I kind of did mine by accident, so I found the following worked for:

1. Run the setup.exe
2. Select the home environment that the instant client is installed into
3. You should have 3 levels on the tree, make sure you only select the bottom node, the click remove, it should prompt you to confirm that you are going to remove the instant client and some other stuff.
4. Once that finishes do the same with the 2nd level node and once that is gone it removes the top level node/home as well

cheers
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue on linux, I accidentally installed instant client. what you do is run the `runinstaller` with `-deinstall -home` (full path to oracle home) arguments

Mine looked like this

```
./runInstaller -deinstall -home /opt/oracle/db/product/12.1.0/client_1
```

That should remove everything. It is odd because all the documents say just run OUI but the instant client does not come with any deinstallation programs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Oracle Universal Installer but you need to start from the lowest level of the repository. If you directly select the whole environment, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

"You can use the Oracle Universal Installer but you need to start from the lowest level of the repository. If you directly select the whole environment, it won't work."

This is the correct explanation!