# Oracle DataAccess - Entry Point Not Found

Tags: .net, oracle, dll, oracle11g, oracle12c

I'm developing a winforms application with oracle database.

Everything worked fine until I had to reinstall oracle 11g. I was able to connect to the database and run my application.

Now I'm receiving the following error:

> The procedure entry point ons_subscriber_cancelcallback could not be located in the dynamic link library oraons.dll.

I also have a 12c version installed for another application.
My environment variable path is like this:

> C:\Oracle\11g\product\11.2.0\client_1;C:\Oracle\11g\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Oracle\12c\product\12.1.0\client_1;C:\Oracle\12c\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;

In  my project I'm using the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` version 4.112.3.0 that I copied to the folder that contain my .exe file.

The new oracle  installation does not have this dll file in the `odp.net` folder. Could this be the problem? I'm confused about this, because in my project I referenced the dll file inside the project folder that contains the .exe file. So, from my understanding, I believe that is ok.

But right now,  I'm lost. I already read tons of forums/blogs saying that the path might be wrong or the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` reference, but mine is ok.

Can anyone assist me with this problem, please?

Comment: When you reinstalled Oracle 11g did you select component "Oracle Data Provider for .NET"?

Comment: It is not a good idea to have more than one Oracle Client installed (unless it is only the Instant Client). Why not deinstall everything and install only Oracle 12c?

Comment: I believe I selected the component "Oracle Data Provider for .NET", is there a way to check it? And I have to have both versions, I have old softwares that depends on 11g, a winforms application that I'm developing that depends on 11g and a new web api application that depends on 12c managed data provider.

Comment: For ODP.NET Managed Driver you don't have to install full Oracle 12c client. You can download and install ODP.NET Managed Driver separately: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Comment: You can run the Oracle installer more than only once. There you can check selected components.

Answer (score 0):

In your `*.csproj`, resp. `*.vbproj` edit your reference to ODP.NET like this:

```
    <Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
```

Attributes like `Version=...` or `processorArchitecture=...` are not required. Your application will load the correct `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` depending on selected architecture and target .NET framework.

Comment: Deinstall all your Oracle stuff and install only one proper version

Comment: Ok, I deinstalled all 12c stuff and now the error message I'm getting is `Unable to load DLL 'OraOps12.dll'`. It seems like my project is using 12c and not 11g. The dll that it should look for is `OraOps11w.dll` and not `OraOps12.dll`. There is a way to fix it? A project config maybe?

Comment: I said "deinstall **all** your Oracle stuff" not only 12c. Locks like you messed up your Oracle installation, check also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Comment: Sorry. I deinstall **all** oracle stuff and reinstall the 11g. And now it works. But **this** problem was because I used a `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` from 12c to test and I forgot about it. Once I change it back to the right `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` (from 11g) it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add an answer about the installation problem so I can accepted it?