# Addressing ORACLE_HOME values diversity

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle11g

I have checked my ORACLE_HOME in 3 different ways in my windows 32-bits PC in this order:

1.- In cmd, if I type `echo %ORACLE_HOME%` the result is just:`%ORACLE_HOME%`, so no current path. Why?

2.- In regedit, under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1`, the stored value is `C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1`

3.- Finally, in the variable Path in Environment variables these are the oracle-related ones values (I disguise the others by using asterisks) in the same order they appear:

`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oracle_python\instantclient_11_2;C:\oracle\32bit\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;*;*;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;*;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin`

In addition, I operate with Oracle only in two ways basically: I use SQL Developer daily but also I do some scripting in Python by using the cx_Oracle library.

My question is whether I have properly optimized the ORACLE_HOME variable or not, I mean would an expert in Oracle agree with this current scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `echo %ORACLE_HOME%` then you interrogate the **Environment** variable `ORACLE_HOME`. In your case it is not set.

Some tools use (only) the Environment variable for `ORACLE_HOME`, other use the Registry value. I think most programs use both and give precedence over Environment variable.

I assume for your Oracle Client following folders are relvant:

```
C:\oracle_python\instantclient_11_2
C:\oracle\32bit\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin
C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin
```

Looks like you installed Oracle client three times (all into different folder). I do not consider this as an optimized setup. My recommendation is to remove all of them and make one single proper installation.

Check also [How to uninstall / completely remove Oracle 11g (client)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client) in case of problems.