# VBA ODBC Oracle Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 193: (Oracle in instant client_11_2, C:\...\SQORA32.dll))

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, odbc

I am trying to create an ODBC connection in a VBA script to an Oracle database, and I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '-2147467259  (800004005)':
Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 193: (Oracle in instantclient_11_2, C:\apps\oracle\11.2.0.3\instant-32\SQORA32.dll)
```

- When going to `%systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe` I can see my driver "instantclient_11_2" and the file "SQORA32.dll" and it works perfectly when connecting to the db in Python.
- When using regedit, in  `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers` I can see the driver too.
- Here is my code, I tried two different connection strings:

  -`strCon = "DRIVER={Oracle in instantclient_11_2};DBQ=MyDBQ;UID=MyID;PWD=MyPWD"`

  -`strCon = "Driver={Oracle in instantclient_11_2}; " & _
               "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
               "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
               "(HOST=MyServer)(PORT=MyPort))" & _
               "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MySID))); uid=MyID;pwd=MyPWD;"`
- My MS Excel version is in 32 bits and so is my driver (SQORA32.dll) so I assume it doesn't have anything to do with a 322/64 versions problem, but I may be wrong.

Any help/advice/solution is welcome.

Comment: Please let us know when you succeed with 32bit driver. :)

Comment: @cyboashu I tried with both 32 and 64bit drivers, I have the same error in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You use 32 bit Excel. You must also install 32 bit Oracle Client, I assume this is the case since folder is named "C:\apps\oracle\11.2.0.3\**instant-
32**\". But verify where you downloaded the client, there are only minor visible differences between 32 and 64 bit version.

For example filename is `SQORA32.dll` for both, 32 and 64 bit version.

However, check registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers` instead of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers` in order to see the 32 bit ODBC drivers.

Update your registry if needed.

Also check whether folder `C:\apps\oracle\11.2.0.3\instant-32\` is in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I already replaced the `SQORA32.dl` by the one from the 32 bit version and also tried with the one from de 64 bit version. But I still had the same error.
The `PATH` is fine as well. And I have the right driver in regedit `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers`. Any other idea ?

Comment: No, you have to check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers`! You look at location for 64 bit drivers. You have to install entire Oracle client 32 bit version, you cannot replace single DLL's this will not work.

Comment: Mea culpa, wrong copy/paste. I checked `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers`.
I uninstalled my version and download a new one and install it, but I have the same error.

Comment: Now it gets difficult. Again check carefully whether your Excel is 32 bit and **all** installed Oracle components are also 32 bit. Check all folders in `PATH` environment variable (i.e. Oracle 64 bit folders must not come first - if existing). Maybe something was left when you uninstalled Oracle, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Comment: I carefully checked that everything was gone before reinstalling everything. But thank you. I finally did everything in Python (sql connection and excel file filing). But as far as I researched, it seems that Oracle and Excel don't go along very well.