# Error while installing Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, installation

I have installed Oracle 11g in my laptop and it worked well and able to login into SQL> through console. Then after I have uninstalled (deleted oracle folders and even in services) and tried to install it again. But now I'm unable to install. Got:

> **OUI-10158 error:** unable to create directory on the specified path

And in install product tab it is getting stopped at 8%. I have tried installing many times directing to different paths.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Answer (score 0):

**First**, try completly uninstall Oracle client and different Oracle components. 
**Second** things you can check is permission to you disk. 
**Third** is check you antivirus settings.

If this not works let me know - i try find something different reason.