# Oracle 11g 32/64-bit | Bad Installation?

Tags: oracle, permissions, odbc, registry, drivers

everyone. If you don't want to read through it all, the question I have is: **What would cause the Oracle 11g Client Installer to not install all of the registry keys properly?** I'm not sure how specific this is to my environment, so I'll try to be as specific as I can and this first paragraph *may not* be relevant. If it's not, I apologize.

I'm installing the Administrative deployment of the Oracle 11g Client Installer, and after installing all of the 32/64-bit ODBC Drivers, testing the credentials, SunGard EAS 11.5, etc... I receive an error from EAS 11.5 telling me...
[image: Unexpected Server Error]

Lucky for me, *that's me!* The problem is that other people are already in EAS so *obviously* it's not a server failure, which, since **every** machine is Windows 10 r14393 64-bit, leads me to the only difference between the environments: The Registry.

During the installation, I change the REG_SZ `insta_loc` in `HKLM\Software\Oracle\` from `C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory` so it installs correctly. In a *good* install, the following registry keys appear:
[image: Properly Installed Registry Keys]

Lately, only the following keys have been appearing, when installed from either my Network (Admin) Account, or the local Administrator, over the network *or* locally from the HDD:
[image: Badly Installed Registry Keys]

Can anyone help me figure out (or answer) why the Oracle Installer(s) would only install certain registry keys? I feel like the only thing that would interfere with an install is permissions, but I've tried the same two Admin accounts I've previously and *successfully* installed this on to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: The upper screenshot is certainly not a *good* install, it's a big mess. The lower screenshot looks much better as it should be. I strongly recommend to remove **all** these Oracle installations. Normal "Uninstall" will properly not succeed, see [How to uninstall / completely remove Oracle 11g (client)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client) for manual remove. Then if you need 32+64 bit Oracle, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Answer (score 0):

I recreated one of the computers in a different group policy and the install worked. The original group policy I had them in was set to automatically install certain .MSI files, and I believe those files wrote to directories with the SYSTEM account instead of using User privileges which disallowed me from writing to the directories and creating the necessary keys.