# How to remove Oracle when universal installer neither deinstall app do not work

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle 11.2.0 client installation which I need to uninstall in order to start over.

When I tried to use universal installer, a popup message appeared telling that I have to use the "deinstall" application.

When I used deinstall application, this error appears:

```
Checking for required files and bootstrapping ...
Please wait ...
ERROR: Cannot find the file oui\lib\win64\msvcp60.dll in the ORACLE_HOME C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1.  You must download the standalone version of the deinstall tool from OTN to deconfigure/deinstall this Oracle Home.
cannot remove directory for C:\Users\jaime\AppData\Local\Temp\OraDeinstall-12-2016_21-15-35: Permission denied at C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\deinstall\bootstrap.pl line 179
        1 archivo(s) copiado(s).
        1 archivo(s) copiado(s).
El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
Se ha(n) movido         1 directorio(s).
```

In fact, this is a Win32 installation and I have a 64 bits PC. Now, I am blocked without the possibility to do anything to deinstall it.

Any help please?

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/8450726/3027266

Answer (score 0):

in regedit, remove main registry keys.Main keys are:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE
If you have any windows service remove the keys relates to oracle in:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services
In there are any variable in: "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment " then delete them here.
then restart the PC and after windows powered on go to %ORACLE_HOME% and remove all of binaries.
Regards,
Mohsen