# Unable to uninstall Oracle 11g Database Express Edition

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, uninstallation

I am attempting to uninstall Oracle 11g database and do a reinstall because of some errors. I am on Windows 10 and was uninstalling from the Control Panel. However, my uninstall window got closed toward the end and now when I go back the Control Panel, it still shows an entry for "Oracle Database 11g Express Edition" which is of 527 MB.

Now it doesn't let me uninstall anymore, it gives me an error [**"1628: Failed to complete installation."**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wecjS.jpg)

I have tried reinstalling the software using the Oracle universal installer but that only gives options to Repair and Remove. Clicking Repair or clicking Remove gives [**"Error 1605: This action is only valid for products that are currently installed."**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6USl.jpg)

*How can i reinstall the database?*

Comment: Have you tried an "official" procedure from the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#XEINW134  ?

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Answer (score 5):

go to C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information and delete all the files over there and try running the Oracle Universal Installer (Oracle XE) again.

Answer (score 0):

Use command prompt in administrator mode and open your installation path
and Run command like this.

msiexec /a "Oracle Database 21c Express Edition.msi"

it works