# Unable to uninstall Oracle products

Tags: oracle

I am facing an issue while uninstalling Oracle products.
To uninstall my oracle home i had to run the deinstall.bat within the deinstall folder and received below error.

```
Network Configuration check config START

Network de-configuration trace file location: C:\Users\rampa\logs\netdc_check2017-05-15_10-32-15-PM.log
UnsatisfiedLinkError exception loading native library: oranjni12
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\rampa\AppData\Local\Temp\deinstall2017-05-15_10-31-30PM\BIN\oranjni12.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
ERROR: oracle.net.common.NetGetEnv.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

I find oranjni12.dll present within the BIN folder, but i don't understand how the path is taken (or calculated) with the temp path and timestamp (and hence incorrect).
I have set my ORACLE_HOME environment variable in Windows correctly as shown below.

```
C:\app\rampa\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\BIN>echo %ORACLE_HOME%
C:\app\rampa\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1

C:\app\rampa\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\BIN>dir oranjni12.dll
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 8423-3F8C

 Directory of C:\app\rampa\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\BIN

05/08/2014  08:35 AM           105,984 oranjni12.dll
           1 File(s)        105,984 bytes
           0 Dir(s)  132,554,211,328 bytes free
```

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, if you have uninstall problems, follow these steps:

1. Stop the listeners and go into Control Panel, Administrative Tools,
   Services and stop all oracle related services.
2. Use regedit and delete Oracle from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE
3. Delete c:\program files\oracle

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Would it also remove Oracle services from Services ?

Comment: Well no, you can choose to stop or disable the services.  Then you reinstall.

Comment: The trick was to open Oracle Universal Installer and uninstall the products mentioned within the DB Home - you have to select each component individually. And later i deleted the folders manually as you said, and also the registry keys. Thanks a lot!!