# Oraclie 12c Client 32 Bit installation

Tags: oracle, oracle-client

I am new to Oracle. Firstly, I have installed Oracle client 12C 64 bit and after that I am trying to install Oracle client 12C 32 Bit. I am keeping them in entirely separate directories. I tried it by running different user and by same user as well, but it abruptly stops just before installation. As soon as I click on Install , it disappears. Please help.

Comment: Maybe your java installation is corrupt. Are you able to launch Java JDK installer 32Bit and 64 Bit?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to delete files in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory\`, resp. `c:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\`. Remove also Oracle directories from `PATH` environment variable.

After that the 64Bit client should be invisible for the 32Bit installer. Of course, after installation of both you should set `PATH` properly, see [BadImageFormatException. This will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100) for details.

Check also [How to uninstall / completely remove Oracle 11g (client)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client) in order to make a full and clean uninstall.