# remove oracle multiple home

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I don't know what I did. I accidentally installed multiple Oracle on my machine. It could have been that I did not realize I installed successfully. I end have 5 Oracle home folders

anyway, I kept having problem connecting to Oracle. SQL developer works, but sql/plus and C# have not been working.

There is a chance multiple Oracle Home cause the problems. I don't know. I decide to uninstall and reinstall again and see what happen

I run deinstaller. It removes successfully on dbhome_5 folder. The files in dbhome_5 folder still exist, I cannot uninstall Oracle in other 4 folders
dbhome_1
dbhome_2
dbhome_3
dbhome_4

Deinstaller could not detect anything. Therefore, I cannot uninstall

Those 5 instances still exist. 
I can install against. That mean dbhome_6. I don't know it will create confusion again.

[How to uninstall / completely remove Oracle 11g (client)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client)

This page tell us how to clean remove. I don't to do uninstall because I cannot. Do I have to manually remove all the files?

I just want the machines to have clean environment before the next installation

I have the feeling that was what happened before. I fail to configure. I uninstall. Then I have 5 folder

I am using Oracle 11 universal installer version 11.2.1.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Having done this before myself, I know how confusing it can get.. worse even, that the configuration for different oracle data access clients about which home to use can be in different places, so your sql plus can end up using one install whereas your c# is using another

I'd recommend to follow the manual removal instructions you found on the linked page; do it for every oracle home you can find (search your entire drive for e.g. tnsnames.ora)

Remove everything (maybe preserve any tnsnames you find as it will make configuring the reinstall a bit easier) and then reinstall it, just once this time:)