# How to connect to Oracle Database from Excel 2016

Tags: oracle, excel-2016

I want to connect to Oracle Database from Excel 2016, to extract DB data returned by a specific query to Excel.

I don't have any DB installed on my computer. I usually connect to Oracle DB using Oracle SQL Developer which takes host name, port number and SID to get connected. In such case, how do should we set up the Excel?

Can anyone please help!

Comment: Hi Nancy, this should be able to point you in the right direction:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48196768/connecting-to-oracle-database-through-excel

Comment: Hey, That blog is for someone trying to connect to Oracle database directly. I connect to Oracle DB using SQLDeveloper and hence would not have a full fledged Oracle installed on my machine.

Comment: Correct, but you would be able to define a DSN to the external database and then reference it using the question I linked to.

Comment: doing oracle database via Excel and Access is usually not going to be...fun. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith : I need to update Excel sheet with the table from the oracle query to match it with query from postgres. Now, the postgres connection works on Excel, but Oracle is giving a lot of issues.

Comment: It would seem, that the question is not related to Oracle SQL Developer, so the #oracle-sqldeveloper tag should not be applied. I vaguely recall, that many MS tools interpret SQL queries given to them and then re-construct them, before sending to the actual DB, resulting in all kind of "fun". Sometimes this can be turned off, so the query is passed to DB unchanged. You might look for that. You may also have better luck by importing data from one DB to another (e.g. export to CSV and import from CSV) to match them in the DB.

Comment: As for not having Oracle DB locally, it does not matter. What does matter is if you have an Oracle Client installed locally (or a install-less Instant Client), so you can use that with Excel. (Oracle SQL Developer uses a built-in Oracle Client, so it works without a separate Client installation, but you can't leverage that built-in Client from Excel.)

Comment: One more possible scenario: Use Oracle SQL Developer to query the data and then export the result to an Excel file - that's something the Oracle SQL Developer was capable for "ages", so even old versions of it should be able to handle this. (Or you can install a fresh version of it.)

Comment: @NancyJoe so you want to propogate changes from Postgres to Oracle? I was going to say if you want a 'spreadsheet', consider building an APEX web application. Then users can see and update the data from a shared app. No excel, no mess.