# The breakpoint cannot currently be hit after oracle dll change

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, odac

I have a solution with several projects in vb, Visual Studio 2012. I just completed an upgrade task from System.Data.OracleClient to Oracle.DataAccess. When I build and run the solution it works fine but failed once I try to enter login info. When I put a breakpoint and build it in debug mode and try to step through each step, it only hits the first instance for page load and after that throws an error. It never reach the targeted breakpoint.

When I check my dll module, I noticed both the older version of the oracle data access and the newest one. And they both say “Binary was not built with debug information”

Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

**Edit**

I was able to run the command again, in the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 this time. I am getting:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>gacutil /l | find "Oracle."
  Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxx, processorArchitecture=x86
  Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxx, processorArchitecture=x86
  Oracle.Web, Version=2.111.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxx, processorArchitecture=x86
  Policy.2.102.Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxx, processorArchitecture=x86
  Policy.2.111.Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxx, processorArchitecture=x86
  Policy.2.111.Oracle.Web, Version=2.111.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx, processorArchitecture=x86
  Oracle.DataAccess, Version=1.111.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx
  Policy.1.102.Oracle.DataAccess, Version=1.111.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx
  Policy.1.111.Oracle.DataAccess, Version=1.111.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx
  Policy.10.1.Oracle.DataAccess, Version=1.111.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxx
  Policy.10.2.Oracle.DataAccess, Version=1.111.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxx
  Policy.9.2.Oracle
```

Comment: Debug mode doesn't guarantee debug symbols are generated - try a full clean, then ensure "Debugging information" is set to "Full" in project properties > Build > Advanced...

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I don’t see Build when I go to project > properties. That’s weird

Comment: Oops, I was looking in VS2017!  In VS2012 it seems to be under Compile > Advanced Compile Options > Generate debug info.

Comment: Ok. I just checked, mine was set to "Full". I am still getting the issue

Comment: What have you done for "upgrade task from oracle 11 to oracle 12"?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for responding. So far only change of application functions/operations and change of the Oracle references. I removed the older oracle client from the Reference and added the new one

Comment: Once again: What was the old reference, what is the new one?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit The old reference is 2.111.7.0 and the new one is 2.112.1.0

Comment: In this case you changed from Oracle  11.1 to 11.2 (not Oracle 12). Did you also remove Oracle Client 11.1 and installed version 11.2? What do you get by `gacutil /l | find "Oracle."`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit sorry but I am getting 'Command "gacutil" is not valid'. when I run the gacutil /l | find "Oracle." command on VS 2015

Comment: Please put additional information in your question (by editing) instead of a comment.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have edited the original post

Comment: Did you update your Oracle client accordingly?

Comment: Maybe you just need to update the connector in your system and reference the new one.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit sorry I may not know what accordingly is in your term. What I have done so far is change of the Oracle references by removing the older DataAccess client from the Reference and added the new one. Replaced OracleType enum with OracleDbType and updating the references to datatypes from VarChar to Varchar2 etc. Actually the application was using system.data.oracleclient.dll and the task is to change it Oracle.DataAccess.Client dll

Comment: @Hackerman can you please elaborate

Comment: It is really not clear what you did. You say "upgrade from oracle 11 to oracle 12", "change from version 2.111.7.0 to 2.112.1.0",, "change from `System.Data.OracleClient` to `Oracle.DataAccess`" - these are all different things. - So what have you done? Did you install/upgrade any Oracle Client and/or driver on your machine? If yes, how did you make it?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, I understand how confusing my questions are. I am very new to this and this my first time doing this kind of task and did not know how to ask the right questions. I did not "upgrade from oracle 11 to oracle 12" or  "change from version 2.111.7.0 to 2.112.1.0". I only  "change from System.Data.OracleClient to Oracle.DataAccess". No I did not install any new oracle client but it was already there. Looks like someone had already installed it in the machine already. Also sorry for all the confusion. I will update my questions

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to conceal the `PublicKeyToken`, they are public to everybody.

Anyway, I assume you messed up your Oracle installation. Most likely you had a working Oracle Client 11.1 (include ODP.NET) but then you installed ODP.NET (i.e. `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`) version 11.2 but without underlying Oracle Client 11.2.

Remove all your Oracle client installation (consult [How to uninstall / completely remove Oracle 11g (client)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client)) and make a fresh installation of **either** Oracle 11.1 **or** 11.2 - or even the latest version 12.2.