# Error installing Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, oracle, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem when I try to reinstall the ODT 2017: I already had it installed, but when I opened Visual Studio and wanted to check the connection it shows the error "The requested .NET Framework data provider is not found. It may not be installed."

I uninstalled it, and then when I wanted to reinstall it, I was amazed at the error that it was still installed, "Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017 is already installed. Please uninstall and try again."

I don't know if I have a folder or file in a hidden folder...

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure: isn't the first error: "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider" instead of "The requested .NET Framework data provider is not found" ?

Comment: Maybe you have to make a full uninstall of all Oracle components, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Comment: Yesterday I delete all files from oracle and I tried to exec the ODT 2017 but return the same message. Today I am to desinstall the Visual Studio community and after reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I am not exactly sure why this worked but I don't want to mess with it since it is working great right now.

I had tried all the methods of manually removing Oracle software and none of that seemed to work. I started exploring the command line options and was trying to force an uninstall even though it wasn't installed. I was hoping it would clear something out.

From command line I tried:

```
ODTforVS2017_122010.exe /V /uninstall
```

However, instead of uninstalling anything, it launched into the normal install. Only this time, it worked! Go figure.

Just in case this had something to do with it... Just before this, I accidentally started the install for the VS 2015 version which started normally. Was really excited until I realized it was the wrong version. Maybe this cleared something out? No idea...

I have to move on and finish before the deadline. I hope this helps you.

Karl

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me, so I had to investigate further. I was able to solve the problem by manually uninstalling the vsix from Visual Studio (using the Visual Studio 2017 Command Prompt):

`vsixinstaller /a /u:"Oracle.VsDevTools.15.0"`

Then, I simply ran the installer again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that even after my previous uninstall with the wizard, the extension (ODT) still on VS2017 but it was disabled, so i uninstalled it from VS and then installed it again with the wizard