# How to install Oracle client 11gR2

Tags: oracle, client

I am trying to install Oracle client 11gR2 ( win64_11gR2_client.zip ) on a MS Windows machine.

After extract of the zip there is setup.exe. Doubleclick on exe causes a Commando Prompt window to open and immediately close. Unfortunately the window closes to quickly to read the error message.

I can also start the setup.exe from a Command Prompt window. In that case, the same, a new Command Prompt windows opens and closes immediately.

How can / should Oracle client be installed? Is there a instruction that describes how this feat is to be achieved?

BTW, I am looking for the Oracle Data Pump utilities for that Oracle database version. Oracle provides a lot for information on these utilities but unfortunately not on how they should be installed.

Are these part of the Oracle client?

Comment: Hi, can you identify which operating system (e.g. Windows 10)?

Answer (score 0):

Run these actions from command line:

```
FOR /D %D in ( %TEMP%\deinstall* ) DO rmdir /S /Q %D
FOR /D %D in ( %TEMP%\OraInstall* ) DO rmdir /S /Q %D
FOR /D %D in ( %TEMP%\CVU* ) DO rmdir /S /Q %D
```

Then navigate to your ORACLE_HOME directory, folder "deinstall" and launch `deinstall.bat`. However, I am not sure whether `deinstall\deinstall.bat` exists already in 11.2. Otherwise you have to run the **Oracle De-install Utility** from [Oracle Database 11g Release 2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.html)

Note, you must run the Oracle setup (or deinstall) as Administrator.

If it does not work, check this one: [How to uninstall / completely remove Oracle 11g (client)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client)

In order to get Oracle Data Pump installed you have to select component "Oracle Database Utilities" in the Oracle Universal Installer (in case of "Custom"). Due to a bug (Bug [17548895](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=1589205.1&id=17548895)) you must also select "Oracle Net".

Or you choose "Full" or "Administrator" installation.

Answer (score -1):

if you install  with Administrator option.u will get the data pump utility.

normally you  should have no problem with installing oracle 11gr2 client

maybe

you can compare MD5 checksum of setup file with oracle website