# I cant install oracle 12c R2 [20802]

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I can't install Oracle Database, because I have error

```
[INS-20802] Oracle Database Configuration Assistant failed
```

- My PC: Windows 10 Pro;
- Intel core I3; 100+ gb free space
- My logs: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AsSF97QkK8MmjyxT7WBwRcyscMtE

**I already tried:**

1. disable UAC
2. Disable antivirus
3. Install Microsft vc 2010 x32
4. editing localhsot
5. root for perl.exe

Appreciate if someone can help me!

Answer (score 6):

Look into your %Program Files%\Oracle\Inventory\logs where you will find the reason for error.

I also encountered similar problem where I installed **Oracle 18c XE**,

Oracle Database 18c we are introduced to a new concept: Image Based Installation.

In Image Based Installation the Oracle Universal Installer of 18c takes the location of our setup.exe file and assigns it as its db_home location. That’s why before we start extracting the content of this file, we first need to decide where we want to create our db_home directory.

Mistake I made was I had the setup.exe in D://drive and for others location left as default(which is C:/ drive)

> Solution:

1. Copy and extract the entire folder which contain setup.exe in C://
       Drive.
2. Manually remove all the files in in C:/Program Files/Oracle
   (including Oracle folder)
3. Run the setup.exe as Administrator
4. Leave the other configuration paths as default

(Additional : Satisfy following condition when configuring the password

Oracle recommends the following guidelines when prompted for a password.

- Contains at least one lowercase letter.
- Contains at least one uppercase letter.
- Contains at least one digit.
- Is at least 8 characters in length.
- Uses the database character set, which can include the underscore (_), dollar ($), and pound sign (#) characters.
- Should not be an actual word.

)

Answer (score 1):

You can find in your logs:

```
SEVERE:  [Jan 18, 2019 4:32:04 PM] [FATAL] [INS-35955] The Database software home 
(C:\ORACLESOURCE) is already registered in the central inventory. This tool can only be 
used in a non-registered Database home.
ACTION: Choose a different location as Oracle home.
```

Try install Oracle in another directory.

Comment: or remove existing installation completely, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for your help - i already try it, but it doesn't help me As i understand my logs - error in perl.exe Maybe you know how to fix it ?

Comment: @Shriram Navaratnalingam 's answer can solve `The Database software home 
 is already registered` error .

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue with error code "[FATAL] [INS-35955] The Database software home
(C:\ORACLESOURCE) is already registered in the central inventory. This tool can only be
used in a non-registered Database home."

*Moved the setup to a different folder and tried installing. It worked.*