# Uninstall Oracle 11g XE from command line

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, windows-7, oracle11gr2

I need to uninstall Oracle 11g XE Server in silent mode from CMD on Windows 7. I've tried

```
setup.exe /s /f1"OracleXE-remove.iss" /f2"oracle_uninstall.log"
```

But there is no reaction, no error, no log. User is administrator and is in Oracle DBA group.
Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: "*The `deinstall` command removes standalone Oracle Database installations*" - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47798/deinstall.htm#NTDBI006

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client