# uninstall Oracle 12c from system

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am not expert at oracle database, i was using the oracle server but now I wanted to remove that. So for removing the oracle server I have deleted the installation folder instead of using the oracle de-installer. But I can see some services in my system. Can some one please help me to remove those configurations as well.
Please excuse my silly mistake.

[image]

Comment: What operating system are you using? And what happens if you run the de-installer?

Comment: windows10. Now i not able to find the de-installer any more as wiped out everything.

Comment: Check also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Comment: To the down voter , can you explain why the question is bad ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really Oracle problem any more, but Windows operating system's.

As you already are in "Services", double-click its name to see both

- service name
- display name

as sometimes they differ. Then open Windows' command prompt and run

```
sc delete "OracleJobSchedulerORCL"
```

where `OracleJobSchedulerORCL` is the *service name*. Double quotes aren't needed if there are no spaces in the service name.

If successful, you'll see the

```
[SC] DeleteService SUCCESS
```

message.

Comment: Can you please also help me to check is there anything else i need to remove to completely wipe out the oracle server.

Comment: Check Windows Registry; search for "Oracle", but - be careful when deleting stuff from registry.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to Uninstall Oracle :

Run CMD as Administrator.

Provide Path and Enter C:\user: cd $ORACLE_HOME\deinstall\deinstall.bat
(Search deinstall.bat file and then provide path accordingly )

It will Ask Y/N : Give Y

Then It will Ask chose from given option: Select Client Oracle Home - Enter 5

It will Ask Y/N : Give Y