# Completely uninstalling Oracle Database 18c

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

I've installed Oracle Database 18c on a Windows 10 OS.  At this point I'd like to completely uninstall and start over.

If I go to the Control Panel Add/Remove or Uninstall Programs, I don't see it listed there.  I can delete the folder it's unzipped to - but it definitely isn't cleanly uninstalled.

Is there a way to completely uninstall Oracle Database 18c?  Thanks much.

Comment: The uninstaller is the usual way of doing it. If it does not work, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Answer (score 0):

Use **Oracle Universal Installer**; that's the way you should be using while (un)installing Oracle software.

If you just delete folder(s), Windows Registry will still contain info about Oracle so ...

Comment: I don't know about 18c, but I know that when I've needed to uninstall earlier versions on Windows, the Universal Installer did not completely eradicate the installation. As best I recall, it left vestiges in the registry, and the oracle inventory.  I found I had to delete two high-level directories and the HKLM/software/oracle registry tree.

Comment: Thanks.  I downloaded ODAC 18.3, but when I go to install it it says I need to have Visual Studio.Net installed.  Do you need to have that installed to use Oracle Universal Installer?