# Why Oracle Database XE 18c is not installing in windows 10?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-xe

I installed Oracle Database **18c** **version 18.4.0.0.0** .It installed successfully in first attempt. I uninstalled it accidentally.Now i am trying to install it again into my laptop  (**Windows 10 Home**). the progress get stuck at a point every time.I am new with this technology please mention if any further detail will required.[This is image where installation get stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv2tk.jpg)[This is the image of directory >product/18.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDG4l.jpg)

Following steps already tried after uninstall.
i)Deleting registries related to oracle.
ii)Removed services related to oracle.
iii)Removed directory "app\User\product\18.0.0" .
iv)Removed Environment variable path.

Comment: Delete temp folders `%TEMP%\deinstall\`, `%TEMP%\OraInstall\` and `%TEMP%\CVU*` (e.g `%TEMP%\CVU_11.1.0.2.0_domscheit`) if existing. Maybe this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Comment: I already tried but still facing same problem.I removed the oracle from registry but issue not resolved

Comment: If you don't have any oracle related installation delete inventory folder and double check no left over services. Close everything except installation sometimes installation expects user input to unblock firewall most probably netca to unblock port 1521

Comment: @Kumar Thank you  but as i mentioned  i am not familiar with this technology. Can you please guide me more specifically,i mean step wise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove `Oracle`or `Inventory` directory in `C:\Program Files\Oracle\`(caution if there are no other oracle installations other wise edit manually inventory.xml and remove xe home element). From elevated command run `services.msc` double check oracle related services are not in invalid state or does not exist(services should be removed with `sc delete` not registry entries)

Comment: I followed you but still facing same issue.@Kumar

Answer (score 3):

There are some issues with XE 18.4 on Windows that lead to stuck or hung installations. These will be fixed in the next major release of XE. Here is what you can try:

1. Is ORACLE_HOME or TNS_ADMIN set in the environment? Go to a command prompt, type "set". You will need to temporarily unset any such environment variables.
2. Are you using Windows 10 Home Edition? It is not supported and the installer is not properly checking for it in the Prerequisite check.
3. Are you using Server 2019? Also not supported with 18.4.
4. On your network adapter that you are using, check (enable) "Client for Microsoft Networks" and "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks".
5. Check to see if Netbios is enabled on your network connection, and enable it if not:
   See this link for more info:

http://ecross.mvps.org/howto/enable-netbios-over-tcp-ip-with-windows.htm

6. In some cases, antivirus has interfered with an installation.  Try disabling anti-virus
7. Try creating a local user and adding to local administrator group and then log in and install as that user.

Comment: I am using windows 10 Home. I also disabled antivirus while installing it but not works.