# Oracle C# Connection Unidentifiable error

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

I am new to C# and trying to connect to an Oracle database in a simple piece of code. I have been getting a lot of connection errors and have tried to solve them through Google search and solved them.

I am now at a point that I am getting an error at the `conn.Open();` statement:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll
>
> Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

I don't know what this error means. I tried and searched a lot but couldn't find anything for this.

Code :

```
string connection_string = "Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=system;Password=6677";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connection_string);
conn.Open();
```

I also tried many other `connection_string` including

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =" + "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =localhost)(PORT = 1521))" + "(CONNECT_DATA =" + "(SERVER = DEDICATED)" + "(SERVICE_NAME = XE)));" + "User Id=system;Password=6677;"
```

Nothing worked.

[image: The Main Error Window]

[image: Libraries]

[image: Environment Variables]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `%PATH%` you really messed up your Oracle installations.

Remove all of them properly (see [How to uninstall / completely remove Oracle 11g (client)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client)) and make one fresh installation. If you need the 32-bit and 64-bit Client follow this one: [BadImageFormatException. This will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100)

Answer (score 0):

This can be lot of different things.

1. Try with anohter user "system" is an internal user and has SYSDBA privilege. Can you try adding a new user:

> CREATE USER test IDENTIFIED BY test;

and connect with this connection string:

```
"SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));uid=test;pwd=test;"
```

(you can take a look [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/) for different connection strings)

2. Double check that your client installation. In you screenshot of you environment variable you seems to have 2 clients installed: a 32 and 64 bits. Remove the 32 bits environment variable if your using a 64 bits DLL in your project.

Comment: Can you guide where do I add a new user please.? I am a newbie in this :-
2. Yes if I just installed the 32 bit clients as removing them gave me an ora-12154 error and solution to this was to keep both clients

Comment: The instruction to create a new user is in my answer: connect with sqlplus or sqldeveloper to you XE database and use the following instruction `CREATE USER test IDENTIFIED BY test;`

Comment: I tried creating new user and tested with some other connection_strings too.Didn't worked in this case