# xampp windows and OLD oracle 8 connection

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I'm trying to configure xampp windows to open connection to old version of **oracle 8**
the oracle 8 DB can be contacted (and queried) via toad and instant client version 10.2.
OS Win 10 x64
I have sequentially try to use older version starting from php7 all the way down to php 5.2
error is Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8.dll'

1. instant client is already in path
2. TNS_ADMIN variabel already in environment variables
3. have manually tried to use PECL other version (with correct php version, architecture, and threadsafe.
4. have manually tried to copy the dll from instant client to apache\bin as some forum suggests.
5. have tried x86 and x64 versions to no avail (with corresponding instant client architecture)

still the modul oci8.dll cannot be loaded, and not shown in phpinfo()
the manuals for oracle 12g and 11 g doesn't seems to work

anybody "old enough" to help me with this compability issue ?
help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Maybe you mixed the architecture. All components, i.e. Oracle client and php must be either 32bit or 64 bit, you cannot mix them. Have a look with [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see which files are actually loaded or fail to load.

Comment: Installing more than one Oracle client can be tricky. You should clean up everything carefully before you install any other, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client In order to install both, 32bit and 64bit Oracle client have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: Also install the correct VS Redistributable needed by Instant Client - see the IC download page.  To connect to 8i you'll need a really old version of PHP - unless you want to recompile the OCI8 dll yourself.

Answer (score 0):

after days of trial and error, I finally find the xammp version that can still connect to the old oracle 8.
Download xampp win32 version 1.7.0.

any newer than that and it won't work.
it is because the bundled oci will not be compatible with oracle 8. and manually change and add the .dll into xampp won't work either because of the build parameters.