# Silently Uninstall Oracle 10g from Windows 10

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Currently have Oracle 10gR2 running across a number of machines, I am trying to figure out how to silently uninstall it. No need to retain any data etc.

To install it we currently run the following :

```
@c:\build\buildfiles\oracle\oraclexeuniv.exe /s /f1"C:\build\buildfiles\oracle\oraclexe-install.iss" /f2"c:\build\buildfiles\oracle\oraclexe-install.log"
```

I can see from searching online that a similar method can be used to uninstall, but by calling a file with the correct parameters to facilitate an uninstall. However I cant find any information on what needs to be in this file.

This link https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2413545/silent-unistall-of-oracle-xe does have an example, but when I use that data in my Remove file, I get a error of -3 returned.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Comment: Dont want to go down the "manual" uninstall route unless really have to, if have to do that may just blat the whole machine and start again (but this is last resort).

Comment: You may write a script for it (e.g. in VBS or PowerShell)

Comment: Yes I understand that! Was hoping that executable itself would take care of this, as it seems to when ran in non-silent mode. So just want to know how to run in silent mode.