# Oracle connection ok but ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred when executing queries

Tags: c#-4.0, oracle11g, windows-server-2008-r2, ora-12170

I have some errors executing queries against a oracle 11g database from a .net c# console application. The connection seems to be established properly (the `conn.State` property is `Open` after the following lines)

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
```

but when launching any query I get an **ORA-12170** error (Connect timeout ocurred). I don't think the problem is in the code as the same test against another database works properly.

```
Connection.State is Open

Error: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at Proj1.DB.OracleProj1.GetOpenConn(String connString) in C:\WorkTV\src\projects\OracleProj1\source\Core\Proj1Core\DB\OracleProj1.cs:line 560
   at Proj1.DB.OracleProj1.AddLog(DateTime start, DateTime end, Int32 userID, String ip, Int32 assetID, Int32 segmentID, Int32 flowID, Int32 permissionID, Int32 permissionSubtype, Int32 resultCode, String resultDescription, String resultLog) in C:\WorkTV\src\projects\OracleProj1\source\Core\Proj1Core\DB\OracleProj1.cs:line 3513
   at Proj1.Util.Tool.AddLog(Int32 resultCode, String resultDescription, String resultLog) in C:\WorkTV\src\projects\OracleProj1\source\Core\Proj1Core\Util\Tool.cs:line 177
   at Proj1.DB.OracleProj1.ExecuteNonQuery(OracleConnection conn, String query, String& log, Proj1Object Proj1Object) in C:\WorkTV\src\projects\OracleProj1\source\Core\Proj1Core\DB\OracleProj1.cs:line 638
   at Proj1.DB.OracleProj1.TestConnection(String connString) in C:\WorkTV\src\projects\OracleProj1\source\Core\Proj1Core\DB\OracleProj1.cs:line 315

Connection.State is Closed
```

I can connect to this database through *Oracle SQL Developer*, with the same user, and insert/delete rows successfully.

When trying to connect with *sqlplus* throught command line I get an **ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error**, so I cannot make any test.

All the oracle services are running.

Command `Lsnrctl status` says:

```
Instance "xxx", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
```

Any help related to any of both errors will be appreciated.

Comment: I've just solved the ORA-12560 by copying the tnsnames.ora into the CLIENT_HOME\network\admin folder and connecting to sqlplus specifing the service alias: sqlplus user/password@alias

Comment: Look at inner exception as post it here.

Comment: I've added the full exception to the question

Answer (score 1):

You should try checking your ODP Libraries. This worked for me, my inner exception was about incompatibility between Oracle.DataAccess and Oracle 11g Database.

Check this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) out and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client).