# Oracle instant client with C# windows forms application

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, dll, instantclient

I have been looking for this for long time ,
I have developed Windows Forms App using C # that have to connect Oracle database, 
this app will be used on many PCs using windows XP and windows 7
After long research i have found that i need to use OBP.net for oracle access but problem is i cannot install oracle client on every PC, However i found work around  in [CodePorject Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18692/Instant-Oracle-Using-C)to download 5 DLL files to do the same job

```
OCI Instant Client Data Shared Library
    oraociicus10.dll (Basic-Lite version)
    oraociei10.dll (Basic version)
Client Code Library
    oci.dll
Security Library
    orannzsbb10.dll
OCCI Library
    oraocci10.dll
```

But when i release the app it dosent connect  to Oracle Database 
Please help how i can have my Windows Forms app connecting Oracle Database with no oracle client installed PC and if this is achievable through the above DLLS how i can do that ?

**EDIT:**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OracleConnection Oracle_connection = new OracleConnection();
Oracle_connection.ConnectionString = con;
Oracle_connection.Open();
```

got connection timeout, in `Oracle_connection.Open();` in debugging mode and I dont use TNSNAMES.ORA as my connection string is as

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.20.2.54)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = PRD))) ;User Id=catering;Password=catering;"`
```

Tried to publish the code it worked on Windows 7 PC but didnt work on Windows XP 
`System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception. ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client    at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize()`

Dunno if it's windows related or some DLLs are missing

Comment: "It doesn't connect to Oracle Database" are you getting an exception (which one?) The CodeProject example has some troubleshooting tips, did you read those?

Comment: Do you have an appropriate TNSNAMES.ORA file in the same directory or do you have the appropriate connection string?

Answer (score 2):

There is also fully managed .net connector aka ODP.NET Managed Driver:

- [Installation instructions, Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/odpmbetainstall-1696475.html)
- [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/odpmbeta-1696432.html)
- [Youtube demonstration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1q50HnUh_w)

I've tested it on Windows 8 and Windows XP SP3 with .NET 4.0 framework installed - all working as expected. For deploying, only 1 dll is needed (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll) which weights 6 MB (in comparison with instant client lite which was almost 40 MB).

UPDATE: Probably the best way to use managed oracle driver is via NuGet ([ODP.NET @ nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/odp.net.managed/))

Comment: I've found the performance to be significantly slower than the ODP.net install.

Answer (score 0):

ODP.net is fussy about mixing version numbers. The error message:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception. ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize()

indicates that its picking up the wrong client DLL version somewhere. When I did some development with Oracle and Visual C# 2010 I downloaded the ODP.NET libraries from:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html

I then took the correct version for the version of Oracle I would be working with and used those DLLs in my project. I'm not sure what the restrictions are in redistribution though.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this thread: [The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client)

The DLLs listed there did the job for me (All in the same directory as the exe).