# Access Oracle database from Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I need to be able to access Oracle database from Visual Studio 2008(Framework 3.0/3.5). The Database version is 11g.

But I also may need to access older version of this database going back to the year 2007.
I tired to install Oracle database client 11gR2 on my desktop computer which has Windows 7 Enterprise edition.
It did not run from Setup menu but ran from background it seems.
Did notice a folder in C:/Oracle with 2 files sqlnet.ora and TnsNames.ora, but apart from that I noticed in the c:\windows\assembly there was no Oracle.DataAccess components installed.

Which client or tools should I need to install to be able to access versions of Oracle from Visual Studio 2008?

Assuming you suggest there is a client version for each of the Database versions, Can I install one client version on top of the other.

Now that I have installed the client 11gR2 can you tell me if I need to install it, I do not see an uninstaller under my "All Programs" menu .

Comment: You need the ODAC, you can download it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client) thread helped me. Basically, you get the dlls from that installation file (without installing it) and reference them in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to install [ODAC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html) as mentioned in the comment.

Then in your project you need to reference `Oracle.DataAccess` and in your code you need to include the following

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
```

Comment: why should he remove OraClient11g_home1?

Comment: May be I got it wrong but since he asked about the uninstaller. May be he wants to remove older versions. Not specifically OraClient11g_home1, that was just an example.

Comment: it seems his question was: *Now that I have installed the client 11gR2 can you tell me if I need to install it*. I can't see anything about *How do I uninstall ...*

Comment: So which older and newer versions of ODAC would I need to install. Would I need to install them one upon the other? Or would I need to install one version of ODAC that will also allow access to older Database.

Comment: Are you all telling me that I do not need Oracle database client 11gR2 to be installed on my desktop?   It does not have an uninstaller. How do I uninstall it if  you think I do not need it? Did you mean I should search for the uninstaller on my desktop??