# Oracle Managed Driver User Defined Types

Tags: oracle, odp.net, oracle-manageddataaccess

I have looking for new oracle managed driver functions as I see many things are not supported for user defined types in oracle(OracleArrayMappingAttribute

IOracleArrayTypeFactory etc...),is there a way to support udt types in managed driver

[Oracle ODP.net Managed vs Unmanaged Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583289/oracle-odp-net-managed-vs-unmanaged-driver)

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/intro004.htm#ODPNT8146

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are correct - as of today (6/5/18) ODP.NET Managed Driver does not support UDTs. I would suggest using PL/SQL stored procedures to convert the UDTs into a type or types that ODP.NET can handle. Also, reevaluate your use of UDTs. They have negative performance implications and I would not reccomend their use unless you are forced to (by either Oracle PL/SQL packages that use them (eg Oracle Spatial) or other packages you cannot wrap in another SP.

Alternatively, you could see if you can use ODP.NET Unmanaged driver, but I understand that that may be unacceptable.

Comment: yes we can use unmanaged driver but we want to see can we use managed driver or not ,because managed driver is fully .net code and in memory usage unmanaged driver use native memory so we cant see detail.

Answer (score 1):

After three years, here comes the UDT support of managed driver for .NET and .NET Core:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

and

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/.

The 21.3 release includes the UDT support and you can find further details such as how to migrate existing projects or sample codes in the blog post: [Announcing ODP.NET 21.3 — User-Defined Types for Managed ODP.NET and ODP.NET Core](https://medium.com/oracledevs/announcing-odp-net-21-3-user-defined-types-for-managed-odp-net-and-odp-net-core-836fa81da3ba)

It is just released and I am about to give it a try, so please do not expect me to answer further questions :D. You might want to visit the [GitHub thread](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/56) to join the discussions.