# The provider is STILL not compatible with the version of Oracle client

Tags: c#, oracle, provider

I'm facing an error message of "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client" again and again.

I tried changing `web.config` to force my web app to use my bin's `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`.
I tried adding DLLs as it is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client). I also tried setting x86 in the build options of my project.

I'm getting mad... there is obviously something I'm missing, but I don't know what! Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the oracle client installed on the machine? How is your connection to Oracle being made(tns, direct, etc.)? What version of Oracle are you using? What version of .net?

Comment: the problem was that the application had to run on a server not dedicated, and i haven't priviledges to know the server's settings.   so i can't reach the real cause of the problem i was facing. The solution, after many changes in my application, was to change provider and use Devart. i know that this isn't a real solution, but at least it works, thanks a lot.