# Random "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client" error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle

I have several asp.net pages running on a server which generally works without issue.

However I've had the Server error "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client error" crop up twice seemingly randomly. That affects all of my pages that interact with the DB server.

A simple reboot of the application server solves the issue and the pages run again without problems. Any ideas what could be causing this problem?

Comment: Quite a bit of options available for you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client

Comment: Yes, I see that there are lots of answers to this error in general but none of them relate specifically to my issue which is the application runs normally on the server and then throws this error on the same server randomly which requires a server reboot. I found nothing out there on that.