# Deploying ASP.NET website with ODP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, odp.net

I'm writing this after following more similar questions:

[OracleException (0x80004005) When Connecting to Oracle Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646800/oracleexception-0x80004005-when-connecting-to-oracle-database)

[The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client)

I have a small ASP.NET website which worked well in developer machine but resists itself in a Test Server. When ever the App called the OracleConnection.Open(); I get an rather helpless "Unhandled Execution Error". The full description is below:

In my machine (Developer Machine) it worked like a charm, but On a Test Server it did not work well.

**My Specs**

Developer Machine & Test Server: Win 7, IIS7, Oracle Instant Client 11.2.0.4, .NET Framework 4.0
UAT & Production DB: Oracle 9i Standard Edition
I'm having the DLL(s) in the Bin folder

**My objective**

Not to install Oracle Client in the Deployment machine rather just copy the DLL(s).

**What I have tried out:**

- I have installed the latest Microsoft Visual C++ 2012  Redistributable (x86)
- Set the project settings of Platform Target to x86
- Ok to check whether its an IIS issue, I made a simple C# Winforms application and its alongside its EXE I have copied all DLL(s). I ran it when OracleConnection.Open() is called an Exception is raised and few of its properties are null.

In my C# Winform app, I wrote the following Code:

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string conStr = string.Format(oraConStr, txtHost.Text, txtPwd.Text, txtUser.Text);
            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conStr))
            {
                LogMessage(conStr);
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    MessageBox.Show("Connected");
                }
                catch (OracleException OraEr)
                {
                    displayOracleErrorMessage(OraEr);
                }
                catch (Exception Er)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Er.Message);
                }
            }


        }

        private void displayOracleErrorMessage(OracleException er)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Error {0}\nError Number {1}\nStack Trace{1}", er.Message, er.Number, er.StackTrace));
        }
```

When I run the above app, an Exception occurs but the Exception have null value in its properties of Error Message, Error Number and Error Source as a result of it I get an "Object Reference not set to an instance of a class" error. i.e. `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.get_Number()`

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.get_Number()
   at OracleConnectionChecker.Form1.displayOracleErrorMessage(OracleException er) in d:\TEMP\Test 2013\Projects\OracleConnectionChecker\OracleConnectionChecker\Form1.cs:line 54
   at OracleConnectionChecker.Form1.btnConnect_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\TEMP\Test 2013\Projects\OracleConnectionChecker\OracleConnectionChecker\Form1.cs:line 41
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
OracleConnectionChecker
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Executable/Debug/OracleConnectionChecker.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
Oracle.DataAccess
    Assembly Version: 4.112.4.0
    Win32 Version: 4.112.4.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Executable/Debug/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

> ### Server Error in '/JksbBoWeb2' Application.
>
> Unhandled Execution Error  Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException:
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [OracleException (0x80004005)]
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32
>   errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx*
>   pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck) +1467
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode,
>   OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src) +24
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open() +4444
>   JksbBoWeb2.Default.getMainDataSet(DateTime pStartDate, DateTime
>   pEndDate) +296    JksbBoWeb2.Default.btnToday_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +133    JksbBoWeb2.Default.Page_Load(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +28
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +51    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +772
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408

Ok thinking whether I have missed anything in my webconfig, I am posting same

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
        path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
          assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ora.prod.jksb.com" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=x)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID = ORCL)));PASSWORD=x;USER ID=x;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
    <add name="ora.uat.jksb.com" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=x)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID = ORCL)));PASSWORD=x;USER ID=x;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it easy: you can't. ODP.NET (Oracle.DataAccess.Client) uses OCI, the library from Oracle that handles the actual connection. That isn't a .NET assembly, it's in C++. ODP.NET is just a wrapper to call OCI. That is why you have to install the Client tools.

But there is more. Oracle has release [Managed ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html), which is a full implementation of the protocol (rather than just having a wrapper to OCI). That means you don't have to install the Client tools, you just have to include that single assembly and you are done!

Comment: Thanks! just to ease the confusion, Firstly, I don't need to worry about any 32bit/64bit problems, I simply can download the 64 bit drivers as you have given in your link and go ahead? Secondly I don't need to worry about Oracle Client in Deployment Server, I simply can place this dlls in my project's bin and go ahead? Neither I need to install Oracle Client in Deployment Server.

Comment: Managed ODP.NET isn't compiled for a specific processor architecture, so no difference between 32 and 64 bit. And indeed, you don't need the client tools installed to get Managed ODP.NET to work. You can't use `tnsnames.ora` unfortunately, so you have to connect directly.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem.

I identified an `Old Oracle 9i client` had been installed in the deployment server and such causing a conflict to what ever dll's related to the Oracle deployment. I simply uninstall the Oracle 9i client, removed references in PATH and finally deleted the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE` key in registry and it worked!