# could not connect to oracle 11g from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g

I developed an asp.net application from my 32 machine. I hosted it in a 64 bit server which has a 32 bit oracle 11g. I used the 32 bit oracle.dataaccess.dll to connect to the db server and everything worked fine.

recently the 32 bit oracle 11g(11.2.02) in server got replaced with 64 bit oracle 11g(11.2.04). From there my site started crashing. whenever i opened the site I will get an error

> "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client"

but I can still run the site from my development machine using visual studio 2010 express.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by installing 32 bit ODAC for oracle 11g in deployment server.