# ADO.NET & Oracle error

Tags: oracle, ado.net, data-access

I am getting an error message in a .NET application. I am very new to using Oracle with .NET.

> The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded.

I have installed devart's oracle driver and also oracle instant client from oracle. But getting this error message. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: FYI Oracle now provides the managed ODP.net library which does not require any installation and very little configuration (+has an EF provider)

Comment: Any information regarding that?? Like as I said that I am new to Oracle so I would appreciate any help regarding how to configure it.

Comment: You can watch this video to learn more about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWpx9vBqr-Q

Comment: Oracle Instant Client does not include ADO.NET drivers. You have to install them separately. (or enable the features in "Full Client" installation. Have a look at this answer: [The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client#25412992)