# Exception calling ".ctor" while connecting to an Oracle database (ODP.net)

Tags: oracle, powershell, powershell-2.0, odp.net

This is my code to connect to an Oracle database:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("E:\oracle\product\11.2.0\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll")
$constr = "User Id=system;Password=password;Data Source=SERVER\INST"
$conn= New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($constr)
```

First line is working fine. I can see the assembly is loading and **GAC** is true.

Up to the second line there is no error.

But when it reaches the 3rd line, I am getting this error:

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.Oracle Connection' threw an exception.
>   $conn= New-Object <<<<  Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($constr)
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
>   "

Can anybody advise me on this.

Powershell version is 2.

**Update**

```
PS I:\> [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("E:\oracle\product\11.2.0\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll")

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
True   v2.0.50727     C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess\2.112.3.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

`Oracle.DataAccess.dll` is architecture specific. That means that you have to make sure the PowerShell process and the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` assembly have the same bits (32 or 64).

May I suggest you to use the platform-independent [Oracle managed driver](http://download.oracle.com/otn/other/ole-oo4o/ODP.NET_Managed121020.zip)? It works a lot better than the Oracle client specific `Oracle.DataAccess`.

Also see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31784086/993547).

Comment: I can't install anything on the server. Due to approval from other teams. GAC is showing True that means Oracle.DataAccess.dll is loading properly am i correct? On the server there are two version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll is available one is 2.x and another one is 4. I can load 2.x properly but i am not able to load 4.

Comment: Use the 2.0 version. I guess you have to install another client version to get it working then. Or use the managed version which is just copy/paste.

Comment: How would i know which is managed version.  I am not a expert of Oracle

Comment: There is just one. Use the latest version. I have tested it to work on all recent versions.

Comment: So, what does that help? Did you try the managed driver? The only thing you can read is that it loads the 64-bits driver. I guess your process is 32-bit?

Comment: Machine is 64-bit. I checked that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86684/discussion-between-404-and-patrick-hofman).