# Concerns about tight coupling between ODP.NET and Oracle Client causing deployment issues on webservers with large numbers of applications

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

Just deployed an application using the "Oracle Data Provider for .NET" and received the error "Exception: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client"

Unless I am mistaken, it appears that the version of ODP.NET that one uses in their code must exactly match the oracle client deployed to the server.

I've always worked with the System.Data.Oracle provider which is independent of the oracle client version, and before that ADODB.. and ADO (DAO anyone?). With all of these technologies, they would work with most any Oracle client, and this was very important, both for organization-wide deployment of client applications and for deployment of web-based applications to servers used by many developers.

Does Oracle seriously expect us to deploy ONE SINGLE oracle client version across our entire enterprise? Under this scenario, how would we upgrade that version later, without re-compiling and re-deploying our entire application suite?

Am I missing something fundamental here, or is there truly a tight coupling between Oracle's ODP.NET and the specific oracle client? If so, how could this ever work in a production environment?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client#25412992

Comment: Yes there is a tight coupling. In practice, people sometimes deploy several versions of ODP.NET+Oracle Client. They can exist side by side as long as you are aware of issues such as the policy DLLs. XCOPY packaging makes it easier to bundle a version of ODP.NET+client with your application. You could also use ODP.NET, Fully managed driver which has no dependency on any Oracle client portion. It is just one dll and is very small. But not all ODP.NET features are supported with it.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have been more clear, my question was not HOW to do it or CAN it be done, it was SHOULD you do it.   Having a version dependence with a specific oracle client just seems to be asking for a world of pain later down the road.