# BadImageFormatException of .net oracle provider

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am using Visual Studio 2012 (64 bit) and oracle 11g (64 bit). When I go to connect oracle database occurring following error.

> Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.
>   This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit
>   Oracle client components installed.

I have spend many times to solve this problem. But did not do that.

**Sample Code**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OracleClient; //Add This

namespace Oracle_database
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();

            //using connection string attributes to connect to Oracle Database
            con.ConnectionString = "User Id=abc;Password=12345;Data Source=ORCL";
            con.Open();

            DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-760);
            DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-760);

            string sd = fromDate.Year + fromDate.Month.ToString("00") + fromDate.Day.ToString("00");
            string ed = toDate.Year + toDate.Month.ToString("00") + toDate.Day.ToString("00");

            var cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = String.Format("Select E.c_Date, E.c_Time, E.l_UID, E.l_TID from tEnter E where E.c_Date>='{0}' and E.c_Date<='{1}'", sd, ed);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (!reader.HasRows) continue;
                if (reader[2].ToString() == "-1") continue;
            }
            // Close and Dispose OracleConnection object
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");

        }
    }
}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: whats the platform target that you have in your visual studio for this project? (configuration manager)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is a 32-bit application, a 64-bit version does not exist. It depends on target architecture in your compiler settings weather you need the 32 or 64 bit Oracle Client.

Then, namespace `System.Data.OracleClient` is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for many years, you should not use it. Use the [driver from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html) instead.

Have a look at this answer, there I provided some details:
[The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client#25412992)

Some more comments:

You should close/dispose the `OracleDataReader` after you have use it.

Use bind-variables instead of hard-codes strings:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select E.c_Date, E.c_Time, E.l_UID, E.l_TID from tEnter E where E.c_Date>= :sd and E.c_Date<= :ed";
cmd.Parameters.Add("sd", OracleDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = fromDate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("ed", OracleDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = toDate;
```

Then you also don't have to take care about any `ToString()`  methods.