# Unable to handle error at C# Project

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2013, database-connection

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNwe4.jpg error.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEocU.jpg details.

I'm getting this error at my C# Project and i don't know what to do.
I can't connect to my Oracle Database.. I'm using 12.1.0 Oracle Client and Visual Studio 2013 v. 12.0.21005.1 (.NET Framework v. 4.6.01055).
As the error describes "not compatible with the version of Oracle Client" i think it must have something to do about those versions. Or that FService.dll is outdated...

Thanks for the help! I really, really apreciate it!

Comment: It seems F# not C#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client)

Comment: It is not a duplicate