# Connect oracle database from visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, oracle11g, connection-string, dapper

I want to write an web-api with oracle database as my back-end and Dapper as ORM.

I have installed odac.client.x86 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and dapper libraries from the nuget package manager. I can able to connect my database from server explorer as shown in below image.[image]

Next i had added a Web Api2 empty controller to my project. 
This is my connection string **Source=Oracle_test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=tams;Password=***********;Unicode=True**.

And my code is

```
   public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        using (OracleConnection db = new OracleConnection("Data Source = Oracle_test; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = tams; Password = tams; Unicode = True"))
        {
            db.Open();
            dynamic result = db.Query("Select NAME from APPLICANT_BATCHES").SingleOrDefault();
            return Ok(result);

        }
    }
```

i am getting exception as ***TypeInitializationException*** as shown in below image
[image]

I am new to dapper and oracle database please help me to connect to my oracle databse and getting results with dapper orm in c#.

My database version is - 11.2.0.1.0 Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in DapperLearning.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception.

Comment: No, that is the outer exception.

Comment: The provider is not compatible with the version of oracle client

Comment: did you install the oracle client? or just copied one/several dll?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/659341/993547

Comment: i had installed through nuget package manager

Comment: My database version is - 11.2.0.1.0 Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Unicode = True` part in your connection string.

According to the MSDN [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.connectionstring(VS.71).aspx) :

> If Unicode is set to true when not using Oracle 9i client software to
>   communicate with an Oracle 9i server, unpredictable results may occur.

Although this is written with an older version of Oracle, I have replicated it with a newer version. I have a project using the Oracle Managed Data Access driver and Dapper to connect to Oracle 11. If I add `Unicode = True` to my connection strings, it stops working while giving me an exception when creating the new Oracle Connection.

Comment: yeah thank u and also one more small problem is there in my connection string. Finally i resolved it.