# Make applications using Oracle 11g and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, plsql, oracle11g

While I was trying to make a c# application using Oracle 11g as specified by Oracle Tutorial on Visual Studio 2017 Community Version it gives a "BadImageFormat" exception.

Above was tried with,
• VS2017 Community Version,
• Oracle 11g XE edition

1) It'd be nice if I could know whether or not ODAC and ODT support above mentioned version of Visual Studio 2017 Community version or should I move into Visual Studio 2015s Enterprise Version. If the case is the latter one would be nice if you could provide me with a download link as Microsoft do not offer previous versions anymore.

2) Is it possible to use Oracle 12c as a local host and make them  databases in local machine without using cloud option?

Thanks,
T.S.

Comment: Typically you get such error when you try to run a 32-bit application with a 64-bit Oracle client {or vice versa). Check this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/a/25412992/3027266

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply but, would you tell me whether or not the ODAC supports for Visual Studio 2017 Community Verison as I saw on Reddit that it does not? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I am not sure but I think it is no problem and should be supported.

Comment: Hi @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for your reply, And anyway My VS2017 Community Version is about to expire so I'll anyway buy Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, Oracle 11g XE - 64 bit Version, ODAC 12.2c Release 1. Hope this set would do right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There s a problem with visual studio 2017 community edition and oracle ODT.
Oracle ODT only works for entreprise and pro edition.
See oracle forum : https://community.oracle.com/thread/4061552

For now it only works VS2015 community with oracle odt 2015, but even at that you have to make sure you use the right version of the packages e.g if you want to use entity framework.

another option will be to use the VS2017 pro trial, it comes with a month and use it until Oracle releases a compatible version

Answer (score 1):

Why is it so difficult to read documentation?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html

> **Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) for Windows Downloads**
>
> ODAC includes Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Oracle Developer Tools
>   for Visual Studio (ODT), Oracle Providers for ASP.NET, .NET stored
>   procedure support, as well as additional Oracle data access software
>   for Windows.
>
> - 32-bit ODAC with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio Downloads
> - 32-bit ODAC Xcopy and NuGet Downloads
> - 64-bit ODAC Downloads - Oracle Universal Installer and Xcopy
> - **Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017 - MSI Installer**
> - Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015 - MSI Installer
> - Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 - MSI Installer