# Oracle Instant Client v12 - how to use without installation with asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, dll, instantclient

Currently we have Oracle Client installed on our server VMs but we'd like to use Oracle Instant Client on Azure Service Fabric (without installation). I managed to get it work with version 11 but with v12 I'm still getting below error (far from connecting to database):

> "The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'
>   threw an exception: The provider is not comatibile with the version of
>   Oracle client"

[image]

Again: it works without installation with Oracle.DataAccess.dll 4.112.3.0 and Instant Client 11.2.0.3 (both x32) but still can't get it to communicate with the newest versions.

I've worked with several Instant Client how-to articles but all of them are very old (~2013) with inactive links to Oracle downloads... Also I cannot use System.Data.OracleClient Namespace because it lacks a few functionalities we need (fe XxmlType or custom types) so I need to reference Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Here are steps I tried. Please point me what am I doing wrong...

1. Downloaded and installed OracleClient 12.1.0.1.0 (Oracle.DataAccess.dll v4.121.1.0) - ODAC122010_x64
2. Copied Oracle.DataAccess.dll from Oracle Home directory (whre it is installed) \odp.net\bin\4 to my project and referenced it
3. Downloaded Instant Client from Oracle website. Version 12.1.0.1.0 - same as Oracle.DataAccess.dll
   [image: Oracle download]
4. Added Instant Client dlls to project (Copy local: Always)
   [image: Instant Client dlls]
5. Also I set up Environment like this:

   ```
   Environment.CurrentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
   ```
6. Works locally (where Oracle is installed) but shows exception when published on Azure

Comment: `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` needs an Oracle Client to be installed. Did you install the Oracle Instant Client also on Azure?

Comment: What is your `ORACLE_HOME` and which folder you have in your `PATH` environment? Perhaps your 4.121 version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` tries to access old Oracle 11 client due to wrong settings of these.

Comment: I din't install it on Azure. Our goal is to have it running without need to install  any Oracle client. I know it is possible - v11 runs fine in our different application (win forms) without installation

Comment: Then you have to use the **ODP.NET, Managed Driver** (`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`), this does not require any further Oracle installation. `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` requires an Oracle client to be installed.

Comment: As I wrote above - it works in our desktop application and now also in web app in Azure WITHOUT any installation. 
Unfortunately I managed it to work with 32bit Oracle.DataAccess.dll 4.112.3.0 and Instant Client 11.2.0.3 but still fails with the newest ones.

Comment: Version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll and Oracle Client have to match, also the architecture (3bit vs. 64 bit) has to be the same. You have to align it, otherwise it does not work.

Comment: All dll's are x64. At least I've downloaded them from x64 download site

Comment: In order to run/install 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle client on one machine you have to make some special settings, follow this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: But again - i didn't install any oracle client ;)

Comment: But again - in this case Oracle.DataAccess.dll cannot work!

Comment: Please describe what do you mean by "in this case" if it may bring anything to this conversation. Why v11 32bit works on clean machine without installation and v12 x64 not?

Comment: As Wernfried suggested above, you really should switch to the [Managed Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/). It requires no client be installed, has no difference between 32 and 64 bit, and makes life much easier.

Comment: "in this case" means: in case you didn't install any oracle client Oracle.DataAccess.dll cannot work - believe it finally.

Comment: Have also a look at this summary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client#25412992