# Error: The provider is not compatible with the version of oracle

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, iis, odac

I have developed a .Net C# based website, which is dependent mostly on Oracle database. To access the DB I have been using Oracle ODAC 11G. (Oracle.DataAccess.dll version: 1.111.6.10).

The website works just fine when I run it locally for testing (Ctrl + F5 on VS 2013). However, after publishing it locally (my PC runs IIS) I encountered a wired error: "The provider is not compatible with the version of oracle".

I have already made sure the app set to run in 32 bit mode in the iis console. But I still can't figure out why the website works when I run it from visual studio, and doesn't work when I publish it.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you running locally, and what version of Oracle is running on your web server?

Answer (score 0):

Check carefully(!) which version of Oracle Client is installed on target machine.

- Does if have the same architecture (i.e. 32 bit or 64 bit) as your `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`?
- Is the version matching. You have to compare even minor version. Just "11.1" is not sufficient.

I recommend [Sigcheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck) tool, i.e.

```
cd %ORACLE_HOME%
sigcheck -s oraociei*.dll
sigcheck -s OraOps*w.dll
```

Check also **which** file `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` is loaded. It might be loaded from GAC (the GAC takes precedence by default) instead of the file you provided. Just can find out which DLL has been loaded like this:

```
var con = New OracleConnection();
Console.WriteLine(con.GetType().Assembly.FullName);
Console.WriteLine(con.GetType().Assembly.Location);
```

See also [The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client#25412992)