# SSIS Reference Error Oracle DataAccess - Call PL/SQL procedure with custom type parameters

Tags: c#, oracle, ssis, etl, script-task

I'm trying to call a PL/SQL procedure with custom type parameters from a SSIS Workflow.

I tried:

- Using the ADO.NET connection manager for Oracle - doesn’t work, since it doesn’t allow for parameter mapping.
- Using the OLEDB connection manager - ok, but only for simple datatypes on INPUT / OUTPUT -> doesn’t solve my problem since I can’t use custom types, and I don’t have the option to use IN OUT parameters (which also occur in the procedures on the Oracle db).

I then tried to make my own custom mapping through C# by implementing all the necessary classes and interfaces used for custom UDT mapping. This way I managed to make it work to pass custom type parameters to and from the procedure. (POC created as a ConsoleApplication).

The tutorial I followed in creating the custom classes: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1139474/ODP-NET-User-Defined-Type-Implementation

I tried using the same code that I used in the Console Application within the SSIS Script Task. And here I met with a strange problem ☹
In order to implement the customType used in the procedure, I used the Oracle.DataAccess reference. Whenever I add this reference to the script task, I get the following error on execution:

[DTS Script Task: Runtime Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p96c.png)

The error occurs as soon as I implement a class that uses a reference to Oracle.DataAccess. The class declaration itself seems to be causing this error, cause even when I don’t use them In scriptMain the error remains.
Whenever I comment out the classes (but leave the reference within the script) the component executes without error…

**CONFIGURATION:**
I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition, 

TargetServerVersion: SQL Server 2017

Target framework on package: .NET Framework 4.5

PATH Environment setting for Oracle client: C:\app\client32\product\12.2.0\client_1\bin

I tried changing the SQL Server target, the Target Framework and some other setting at project and package level but nothing worked.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem so that I can use my C# custom mapping within the Script Task?

Any other solutions offering calling procedures with custom parameters are also welcome :)

Lastly, if anyone knows a good auto UDT mapper I would be grateful :) I tried Odapter - ok but uses Oracle.ManagedDataAccess instead of DataAccess and I can't seem to use OracleDbType.Object there...

EDIT:
I managed to find out that the problem occurs whenever I implement an interface from a reference (f.ex. IOracleCustomType). If I only use this type as a parameter in a method or so, the script executes. As soon as I add a class implementing the interface, the 'Could not load script for execution' error appears..

Comment: Do you try to connect to an SQL Server 2017 with an Oracle driver?

Comment: There might be several reasons, check these ones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client#25412992

Comment: You have to load the OracleDataaccess assembly using reflection, I can't find how i did it before but it was something similar to this: http://roman.tumaykin.com/tools/2015/12/09/Loading-custom-assemblies-into-SSIS-Script-Task-without-installing-them-into-GAC-Part-2.html