# .NET Oracle, error on Oracle.DataAccess unmanaged

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I try to connect my app to an Oracle database with Oracle.DataAccess.dll but i have a message => "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client".

```
try
{
    var str = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder()
    {
        DataSource = "MyDatabase",
        UserID = "system",
        Password = "manager",
        Pooling = false,
    };
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client
}
```

Firstly, i can connect with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll but i need to use BulkCopy so i need to use Oracle.DataAccess.dll with Oracle Client.

I have install Oracle client 12.2 and i can connect to Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2 with SQLPlus

I do not understand where this error came from.
Could you help me ?

Thanks for yous answers

Comment: The oracle client on your machine are 32 or 64 bits architecture? And what about your .NET app, are you running in 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: There could be several reasons, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client#25412992

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a matching version of ODAC to connect to Oracle from Dotnet application

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
I had install ODTwithODAC122011, Add the path of OracleHome to my environment variables "PATH" and "ORACLE_HOME"
OracleHome is install on D: disk, it could be the mistake ?

Comment: @Maverick try to add `OracleHome` and `OracleHome\bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wernfried Domscheit of his answers !
=> [The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client#25412992)

Problem come from version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll and ODAC install on the machine.

And **OracleHome** and **OracleHome\bin** to your PATH environment variable.