# The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client, stuck

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, oracle11g, odp.net, oracle11gr2

This is my first time trying to connect to an Oracle Database through ASP.NET MVC Core and C# using VISUAL STUDIO
I tried so many things but no one really helped me at all.

[image]

I have installed this Nuget Packet: **odp.net.x64**

The question that is rolling in my mind is that it is necessary to install **win64_11gR2_client.zip** (Oracle client for Oracle 11g) in order to make it work.

What i am missing?

Comment: Yes, the ODP.NET (unmanaged) Provider needs an Oracle Client installed. Ensure that the versions match **exactly**. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client#25412992

Comment: Please don't paste images, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit hey pal, how are you?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the question is: is it necessary to use the Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (x64) within the Oracle.DataAccess.dll from nuget package Oracle.DataAccess.x86, and its Dll Version on 2.112.1.0? would it work?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Would it be possible to use a higher version of the Oracle Database Client and a newest version of Oracle.DataAccess?